# Group mysql query by 15 min intervals

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, group-by, timestamp

I've got a monitoring system that is collecting data every n seconds (n is approximately 10 but varies).  I'd like to aggregate the collected data by 15 minute intervals.  Is there a way to consolidate the timestamp values into 15 minute chunks to allow for grouping to work?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
SELECT   FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)/(15 * 60)) AS timekey
FROM     table
GROUP BY timekey;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)/(15 * 60)` for minutes?

Comment: I don't think ROUND is the right function should be used here.
DIV is more appropriate.
`UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) DIV (15 * 60)`
Because SELECT ROUND(1.8), ROUND(2.1) will fall in the same segment, though they shouldn't.
Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3086470/412786

Comment: `ROUND` gives a different 15 minute interval than `DIV`, but both produce 15 minute intervals.

Comment: I think using FLOOR will produce better result than ROUND function : 00:00:00 will be grouped with values up to 00:14:59. I think it is a more natural concept.

Comment: I would use CEIL. If you use 10 min interval, then FLOOR gives 5,15,25 but ceil gives 0, 10, 20 which is more correct splitting

Comment: `FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)/(15 * 60)) * 15 * 60` if you want to get the correct timestamp out of the query

Answer (score 21):

Try this , grouping of records of 15 minutes interval, you can change 15*60 to the interval in seconds you need

```
SELECT sec_to_time(time_to_sec(datefield)- time_to_sec(datefield)%(15*60)) as intervals from tablename
group by intervals
```

Comment: I like this approach the most because it keeps the minute interval as one of the columns imo making it more readable.  Thanks.

Comment: This also helped me! Thanks. Needed it for hours so I changed (15*60) to (60*60)

Comment: This doesn't work if the records contain multiple dates, because then all records with the same time across dates are grouped.

Comment: @BenG: Thanks a lot. This just gives me the result I need.

Answer (score 5):

Adaptation of approach 1) below:

```
select Round(date_format(date, "%i") / (15*60)) AS interval  
from table
group by interval
```

Adaptation of approach 3) below:

```
SELECT Round(Convert(substring(date_column, 14, 2), UNSIGNED) / (15*60)) AS interval /* e.g. 2009-01-04 12:20:00 */
FROM table 
GROUP BY interval;
```

A few approaches I've found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html):

1)

```
select date_format(date, "%W") AS `Day of the week`, sum(cost)
from daily_cost
group by `Day of the week` 
order by date_format(date, "%w")
```

2)

```
select count(*) as 'count', 
  date_format(min(added_on), '%Y-%M-%d') as 'week commencing',
  date_format(added_on, '%Y%u') as 'week' 
from system 
where added_on >= '2007-05-16' 
group by week 
order by 3 desc;
```

3)

```
SELECT substring(postdate, 1,10) AS dd, COUNT(id) FROM MyTable GROUP BY dd;
```

(Also here: http://www.bradino.com/mysql/dayparting-on-datetime-field-using-substring/)

EDIT: All the solutions will perform badly on a table with a large number of records.

Comment: well - how would you adapt these to group by 15 minute ranges?

Comment: The same way as ~unutbu did. But he was faster :-)

Answer (score 4):

I started with the answer given above by unutbu but didn't get what I needed and had to add a bit to it.

`Select Created, from_unixtime(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Created)/(15*60))*(15*60)) GroupTime,
COUNT(*) as Cnt
FROM issue i
GROUP BY GroupTime`

This code divides by the 900 seconds in a 15 minute span then floors the value and multiplies it back up by 900, essentially rounding down to the nearest 15 minute increment.

Answer (score 4):

Following query groups rows and creates timestamps at 15 min intervals.

```
Select concat( date(created_dt) , ' ', sec_to_time(time_to_sec(created_dt)- time_to_sec(created_dt)%(15*60) + (15*60)))as created_dt_new from table_name group by created_dt_new
```

E.g Timestamps 
2016-11-09 13:16:29

2016-11-09 13:16:49 

2016-11-09 13:17:06

2016-11-09 13:17:26

2016-11-09 13:18:24

2016-11-09 13:19:59

2016-11-09 13:21:17

Are grouped into 2016-11-09 13:30:00

1. `sec_to_time(time_to_sec(created_dt)- time_to_sec(created_dt)%(15*60) + (15*60)))`

   Upper bounds time to nearest 15 min interval. e.g 12:10 -> 12:15
2. `concat( date(created_dt) , ' ', sec_to_time(time_to_sec(created_dt)- time_to_sec(created_dt)%(15*60) + (15*60)))`

   Generates a timestamp taking the date from the timestamp field.

Answer (score 3):

**Unix timestamps**: floor them to nearest 15 minute using one of the following:

```
timestamp div (15 * 60) * (15 * 60) -- div is integer division operator
timestamp - timestamp % (15 * 60)
```

**Date time**: assuming the datatype does not have fractional seconds, floor them to nearest 15 minute using:

```
date - INTERVAL EXTRACT(SECOND FROM date) SECOND - INTERVAL EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM date) % 15 MINUTE
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ac7c81b953914aec49859ac10c24fa25)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
mysql> **SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())- UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())%(15*60));**
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())- UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())%(15*60)) |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2012-02-09 11:15:00                                                 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

THis Work for me

```
SELECT CONCAT (
        YEAR(transactionDate)
        ,'-'
        ,MONTH(transactionDate)
        ,'-'
        ,DAYOFMONTH(transactionDate)
        ,' '
        ,HOUR(transactionDate)
        ,':'
        ,((floor((MINUTE(transactionDate) / 15)) + 1) * 15) - 1
        ,':59'
        ) AS tmp1
    ,count(*)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY tmp1 limit 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change "15" to whatever interval you want.

```sql
select count(*),
CONCAT(HOUR(col_date),":",(MINUTE(create_date) div 15)*15) as date
from tablename
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY col_date ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not satisfied by GROUP BY.

```
SELECT   datetime
FROM     table
WHERE MOD(MINUTE(TIME(datetime)),15) = 0 AND SECOND(TIME(datetime)) = 0;
```