# Grouping into interval of 5 minutes within a time range

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have some difficulties with mySQL commands that I want to do.

```
SELECT a.timestamp, name, count(b.name) 
FROM time a, id b 
WHERE a.user = b.user
  AND a.id = b.id
  AND b.name = 'John'
  AND a.timestamp BETWEEN '2010-11-16 10:30:00' AND '2010-11-16 11:00:00' 
GROUP BY a.timestamp
```

This is my current output statement.

```
timestamp            name  count(b.name)
-------------------  ----  -------------
2010-11-16 10:32:22  John  2
2010-11-16 10:35:12  John  7
2010-11-16 10:36:34  John  1
2010-11-16 10:37:45  John  2
2010-11-16 10:48:26  John  8
2010-11-16 10:55:00  John  9
2010-11-16 10:58:08  John  2
```

How do I group them into 5 minutes interval results?

I want my output to be like

```
timestamp            name  count(b.name)
-------------------  ----  -------------
2010-11-16 10:30:00  John  2
2010-11-16 10:35:00  John  10
2010-11-16 10:40:00  John  0
2010-11-16 10:45:00  John  8
2010-11-16 10:50:00  John  0
2010-11-16 10:55:00  John  11
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SELECT / GROUP BY - segments of time (10 seconds, 30 seconds, etc)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086386/select-group-by-segments-of-time-10-seconds-30-seconds-etc)

Answer (score 179):

This works with every interval.

**PostgreSQL**

```sql
SELECT
    TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' +
    INTERVAL '1 second' * round(extract('epoch' from timestamp) / 300) * 300 as timestamp,
    name,
    count(b.name)
FROM time a, id 
WHERE …
GROUP BY 
round(extract('epoch' from timestamp) / 300), name
```

**MySQL**

```sql
SELECT
    timestamp,  -- not sure about that
    name,
    count(b.name)
FROM time a, id 
WHERE …
GROUP BY 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) DIV 300, name
```

Comment: oh… didn't get the mysql-flag.. it's a postgresql-query .. but basically this should be possible with mysql, too

Comment: ok .. instead of extract ..
GROUP BY round(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) / 300) should do the trick

Comment: This does not quite work in my case. I want the time to be grouped into 30 minute intervals on the hour and on the half hour - this does it on 45 min and 15 mins the following I would expect p1 and p2 to be in the same period but they are not instead p2 and p3 are in the same haven't figured out why just yet:
 mysql> select round(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-03-14 13:44')/1800) as p1, 
 round(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-03-14 13:46')/1800) as p2,  
 round(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-03-14 14:05')/1800) as p3;
p1=757371  p2=757372  p3=757372 |

Comment: @pHiL's comment is correct on mySql you should use DIV instead of round(/) otherwise the boundry between intervals is wrong

Comment: Just tried it with several datasets and 2nd query works brilliantly for MySQL, which was the OPs concern. Since @sky seems absent, can we get a group consensus on this is the answer?

Comment: I have tried this as well. its showing first record wrong every time 2 minute or 3 minute interval and further 5 minute intervals. 
Note:- i have added a condition to get last 15 mins records.

Comment: the postgres query is partially wrong (the round brackets): i always prefer to say "group by 1" over an explicit expression: select timestamp with time zone 'epoch' + interval '1 second' * round((extract('epoch' from ts) / 300)) * 300 as ts, count(*) from TABLE group by 1 order by 1

Comment: What happens when we do DIV 0 in MySQL one Thanks :)

Answer (score 42):

I came across the same issue.

I found that it is easy to group by any minute interval is
just dividing **epoch** by minutes in amount of seconds and then either rounding or using floor to get ride of the remainder.  So if you want to get interval in **5 minutes** you would use **300 seconds**.

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, 
    to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from timestamp_column) / 300 )) * 300) 
    AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' as interval_alias
    FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY interval_alias
```

```
interval_alias       cnt
-------------------  ----  
2010-11-16 10:30:00  2
2010-11-16 10:35:00  10
2010-11-16 10:45:00  8
2010-11-16 10:55:00  11
```

This will return the data correctly group by the selected minutes interval; however, it will not return the intervals that don't contains any data. In order to get those empty intervals we can use the function [generate_series](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html).

```
    SELECT generate_series(MIN(date_trunc('hour',timestamp_column)),
    max(date_trunc('minute',timestamp_column)),'5m') as interval_alias FROM 
    TABLE_NAME
```

Result:

```
interval_alias       
-------------------    
2010-11-16 10:30:00  
2010-11-16 10:35:00
2010-11-16 10:40:00   
2010-11-16 10:45:00
2010-11-16 10:50:00   
2010-11-16 10:55:00
```

Now to get the result with interval with zero occurrences we just **outer join both result sets**.

```
    SELECT series.minute as interval,  coalesce(cnt.amnt,0) as count from 
       (
       SELECT count(*) amnt,
       to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from timestamp_column) / 300 )) * 300)
       AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' as interval_alias
       from TABLE_NAME  group by interval_alias
       ) cnt
    
    RIGHT JOIN 
       (    
       SELECT generate_series(min(date_trunc('hour',timestamp_column)),
       max(date_trunc('minute',timestamp_column)),'5m') as minute from TABLE_NAME 
       ) series
  on series.minute = cnt.interval_alias
```

The end result will include the series with all 5 minute intervals even those that have no values.

```
interval             count
-------------------  ----  
2010-11-16 10:30:00  2
2010-11-16 10:35:00  10
2010-11-16 10:40:00  0
2010-11-16 10:45:00  8
2010-11-16 10:50:00  0 
2010-11-16 10:55:00  11
```

The interval can be easily changed by adjusting the last parameter of generate_series. In our case we use **'5m'** but it could be **any interval** we want.

Comment: It would have been if it was MySQL. Seems like generate_series is a PostgreSQL function. Too bad.

Comment: First query that is giving just present data only result, it counts middle records of 2 time periods in both time periods. Like in 2 time period, 10:35 and 10:40, it counts 10:40 in both group that is one in 10:35 to 10:40 and 10:40 to 10:45.

Comment: how do I get it only for a certain time period? like a where condition to get data between two dates ?

Answer (score 30):

You should rather use `GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_stamp) DIV 300` instead of round(../300) because of the rounding I found that some records are counted into two grouped result sets.

Comment: THis is correct the round(../300) was not doing it properly on mySql

Comment: For those who are curious, `DIV` in MySQL is a `floor()` of a float division that's safe with `BIGINT`s.

Comment: I have tried this as well. its showing first record wrong every time 2 minute or 3 minute interval and further 5 minute intervals. 
Note:- i have added a condition to get last 15 mins records.

Comment: One should use TRUNCATE or FLOOR instead of ROUND because the rounding behaviour is not well defined and depends on the used C library. https://lists.mysql.com/mysql/93613

Answer (score 28):

For **postgres**, I found it easier and more accurate to use the

[date_trunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)

function, like:

```
select name, sum(count), date_trunc('minute',timestamp) as timestamp
FROM table
WHERE xxx
GROUP BY name,date_trunc('minute',timestamp)
ORDER BY timestamp
```

You can provide various resolutions like 'minute','hour','day' etc... to date_trunc.

Comment: @tmarthal - it shouldn't be upvoted. The original question was for mysql.

Comment: Where do you set the `5` here for the 5 minutes interval ?

Comment: For the above, change the WHERE clause to:
WHERE timestamp > current_timestamp - interval '5 minutes'

Comment: This query does not seem to do what is asked, question is 'every  5' minutes not 5 minutes before now  . answer fit to be downvoted

Answer (score 11):

The query will be something like:

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(
    MIN(timestamp),
    '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:00'
  ) AS tmstamp,
  name,
  COUNT(id) AS cnt 
FROM
  table
GROUP BY ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) / 300), name
```

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if you still need it.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp))/300)*300) AS t,timestamp,count(1) as c from users GROUP BY t ORDER BY t;
```

> 2016-10-29 19:35:00 | 2016-10-29 19:35:50 | 4 |
>
> 2016-10-29 19:40:00 | 2016-10-29 19:40:37 | 5 |
>
> 2016-10-29 19:45:00 | 2016-10-29 19:45:09 | 6 |
>
> 2016-10-29 19:50:00 | 2016-10-29 19:51:14 | 4 |
>
> 2016-10-29 19:55:00 | 2016-10-29 19:56:17 | 1 |

Answer (score 5):

You're probably going to have to break up your timestamp into ymd:HM and use DIV 5 to split the minutes up into 5-minute bins -- something like

```
select year(a.timestamp), 
       month(a.timestamp), 
       hour(a.timestamp), 
       minute(a.timestamp) DIV 5,
       name, 
       count(b.name)
FROM time a, id b
WHERE a.user = b.user AND a.id = b.id AND b.name = 'John' 
      AND a.timestamp BETWEEN '2010-11-16 10:30:00' AND '2010-11-16 11:00:00'
GROUP BY year(a.timestamp), 
       month(a.timestamp), 
       hour(a.timestamp), 
       minute(a.timestamp) DIV 12
```

...and then futz the output in client code to appear the way you like it. Or, you can build up the whole date string using the sql concat operatorinstead of getting separate columns, if you like.

```
select concat(year(a.timestamp), "-", month(a.timestamp), "-" ,day(a.timestamp), 
       " " , lpad(hour(a.timestamp),2,'0'), ":", 
       lpad((minute(a.timestamp) DIV 5) * 5, 2, '0'))
```

...and then group on that

Comment: Hmmm... But the output isn't getting what I am trying to get. It returns one column and I not very sure what the value  of the count is...

Answer (score 2):

How about this one:

```
select 
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(timestamp) - unix_timestamp(timestamp) mod 300) as ts,  
    sum(value)
from group_interval 
group by ts 
order by ts
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on @boecko answer for MySQL, I used a CTE (Common Table Expression) to accelerate the query execution time :

so this :

```
SELECT
    `timestamp`,
    `name`,
     count(b.`name`)
FROM `time` a, `id` b
WHERE …
GROUP BY 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timestamp`) DIV 300, name
```

becomes :

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        `timestamp`,
        `name`,
         count(b.`name`),
         UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`timestamp`) DIV 300 AS `intervals`
    FROM `time` a, `id` b
    WHERE …
)
SELECT * FROM cte GROUP BY `intervals`
```

**In a large amount of data, the speed is accelerated by more than 10!**

*As `timestamp` and `time` are reserved in MySQL, don't forget to use `...` on each table and column name !*

Hope it will help some of you.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that with MySQL probably the correct query is the following:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( FROM_UNIXTIME( CEILING( timestamp /300 ) *300,  
                                 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S' ) , 1, 19 ) AS ts_CEILING,
SUM(value)
FROM group_interval
GROUP BY SUBSTRING( FROM_UNIXTIME( CEILING( timestamp /300 ) *300,  
                                   '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S' ) , 1, 19 )
ORDER BY SUBSTRING( FROM_UNIXTIME( CEILING( timestamp /300 ) *300,  
                                   '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S' ) , 1, 19 ) DESC
```

Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
CONCAT(CAST(CREATEDATE AS DATE),' ',datepart(hour,createdate),':',ROUNd(CAST((CAST((CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE,CREATEDATE) AS DECIMAL (18,4)))/5 AS INT)) AS DECIMAL (18,4))/12*60,2)) AS '5MINDATE'
,count(something)
from TABLE
group by CONCAT(CAST(CREATEDATE AS DATE),' ',datepart(hour,createdate),':',ROUNd(CAST((CAST((CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE,CREATEDATE) AS DECIMAL (18,4)))/5 AS INT)) AS DECIMAL (18,4))/12*60,2))
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your query.

Answer (score 0):

This will do exactly what you want.

Replace

- dt - your datetime
- c - call field
- astro_transit1 - your table
- 300 as seconds for each time gap increase

```
SELECT 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(300 * ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(r.dt) / 300)) AS 5datetime,
    (SELECT 
            r.c
        FROM
            astro_transit1 ra
        WHERE
            ra.dt = r.dt
        ORDER BY ra.dt DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS first_val
FROM
    astro_transit1 r
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(r.dt) DIV 300
LIMIT 0 , 30
```