# MySQL get a minimum and maximum range out of an interval

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ok so I have a range of values like so:

```
Symbol     Timestamp            Volume  Price   Open
NIF     2011-05-10 11:26:01     439757  1.3150  1.3100 
NIF     2011-05-10 11:25:01     439757  1.3150  1.3100 
NIF     2011-05-10 11:24:01     439757  1.3150  1.3100
NIF     2011-05-10 11:23:01     439752  1.3150  1.3100
NIF     2011-05-10 11:22:02     439752  1.3150  1.3100
NIF     2011-05-10 11:21:02     439752  1.3150  1.3100
NIF     2011-05-10 11:20:01     439752  1.3150  1.3100
NIF     2011-05-10 11:19:01     439752  1.3150  1.3100
NIF     2011-05-10 11:18:02     439752  1.3150  1.3100 
NIF     2011-05-10 11:17:01     439752  1.3150  1.3100
NIF     2011-05-10 11:16:02     439752  1.3150  1.3100
NIF     2011-05-10 11:15:01     431752  1.3150  1.3100
NIF     2011-05-10 11:14:02     431752  1.3150  1.3100
NIF     2011-05-10 11:13:02     431752  1.3150  1.3100
NIF     2011-05-10 11:12:01     431752  1.3150  1.3100
NIF     2011-05-10 11:11:01     431252  1.3150  1.3100
NIF     2011-05-10 11:10:02     431252  1.3150  1.3100
NIF     2011-05-10 11:09:01     428252  1.3150  1.3100
NIF     2011-05-10 11:08:01     427242  1.3150  1.3100
NIF     2011-05-10 11:07:02     427242  1.3150  1.3100
NIF     2011-05-10 11:06:02     427242  1.3150  1.3100
NIF     2011-05-10 11:05:01     427242  1.3150  1.3100
NIF     2011-05-10 11:04:02     427242  1.3150  1.3100
NIF     2011-05-10 11:03:02     427242  1.3150  1.3100
NIF     2011-05-10 11:02:02     427242  1.3150  1.3100
NIF     2011-05-10 11:01:02     427242  1.3150  1.3100
NIF     2011-05-10 11:00:02     427242  1.3150  1.3100
```

So between 11:01:02 and 11:26:01 I want to get the maximum, minimum of a price.

Ok, so you'll say that`s easy...use a grouping function, etc. , but it's not that easy.
I need to generate a range of minimum maximums, for an interval so, let's say if the user inputs an interval of 30 minutes, for all day long I need to return a range of minimum maximum of the day broken down in smaller sets of minimum maximum of 30 minutes.
For example:

It's 12 PM now and data comes in from 10 AM, I need minimum maximum range for

```
10:30 (min max range of 10-10:30), 
11:00 (10:30-11:00),
11:30 (11:00-11:30),
12:00 (11:30-12:00).
```

So I bashed my head around on how to do that, basically I tried GROUP BY but that didn`t maintain timestamp, so I thought temporary tables, but have no idea on how would I use it.

Any heads up is appreciated.

Comment: How about dividing your day into slices (timestamp_in_minutes div 30) and grouping by slice?

Comment: Already said that you'll say that, but I don`t need a single value, but a range of minimum maximum. So the range of minimum maximum out of an interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range