# MySQL group by time

Tags: mysql, timestamp, divide

I'm trying to do an sql that retrieves starting time and count of rows , after grouping on segments of time. I already checked that on stackoverflow and I can acheive that doing

```
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_stamp) DIV 30
```

The problem is that I need this to start with a certain time(it may or may not exists between the rows) and even(if possible--not required thought) add the times with 0 counted items, as well.

For example, having a table with this rows:

```
+---------------------+-----------------+
| time_stamp          | id              |
+---------------------+-----------------+
| 2010-06-15 23:00:04 |               1 |
| 2010-06-15 23:00:30 |               2 |
| 2010-06-15 23:01:30 |               3 |
| 2010-06-15 23:03:30 |               4 |
| 2010-06-15 23:04:30 |               5 |
| 2010-06-15 23:06:10 |               6 |
| 2010-06-15 23:06:20 |               7 |
| 2010-06-15 23:06:30 |               8 |
| 2010-06-15 23:06:30 |               9 |
| 2010-06-15 23:06:35 |              10 |
+---------------------+-----------------+
```

and starting with 2010-06-15 23:00:00 for every minute(DIV 60), I would like to have the following output:

```
+---------------------+-----------------+
| time_stamp          | count(id)       |
+---------------------+-----------------+
| 2010-06-15 23:00:00 |               2 |
| 2010-06-15 23:01:00 |               1 |
| 2010-06-15 23:02:00 |               0 |
| 2010-06-15 23:03:00 |               1 |
| 2010-06-15 23:04:00 |               1 |
| 2010-06-15 23:05:00 |               0 |
| 2010-06-15 23:06:00 |               5 |
+---------------------+-----------------+
```

. Would be cool even without the count = 0 cases.

Also..adding every single timestamp and then removing it isn't a solution..

Those are dummy datas, I don't want to divide only by minutes, but by a parameter in php

The correct answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789818/grouping-mysql-datetime-into-intervals-irrespective-of-timezone), but I could only find that through the post marked as accepted.

Comment: what do you mean a parameter?

Comment: this will be a query in a php function

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grouping MySQL datetime into intervals irrespective of timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789818/grouping-mysql-datetime-into-intervals-irrespective-of-timezone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all you want to do is GROUP BY and then use a time function.. in this case MINUTE should do what you want

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
GROUP BY MINUTE(time_stamp)
```

**EDIT:**

after the question edits I believe this query will be closer to what you want to do.

```
SELECT 
  FROM_UNIXTIME
  (   FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time_stamp`)/your_var
           )* your_var
  ) AS timesliced, 
  COUNT(*) AS mycount
FROM tablename
WHERE time_stamp >= '2010-06-15 23:01:45' 
GROUP BY timesliced
```

Comment: **edited**  I don't want to divide only by minutes, but by a parameter, and starting with a CERTAIN date like 2010-06-15 23:01:45

Comment: you need to clarify more.. what do you mean a parameter? I can limit the results to have the date start at that certain date.. but how else would you divide it if not by minutes? thats what the expected results show.

Comment: For example for every X seconds, where X will be as an input from a php function

Comment: @RaduVlad see my edit... I put in a way to input a number of seconds that you want to count by.. called your_var just put in there whatever it is that you will be passing and it'll split the data by that timeframe

Comment: Thanks. The perfect response I believe is not really yours, but here the one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789818/grouping-mysql-datetime-into-intervals-irrespective-of-timezone
Im gonna mark this as correct, due to getting there only because of you and edit in the initial post. Thanks

Comment: do you happen to know if there if any way to display the periods with count = 0?

Comment: @RaduVlad I could probably work up a solution for that.. the issue is you need some kind of identifier to put the 0 in.. so are you going to be using this for every minute of an hour?

Comment: Yes, lets asume so. I also tried putting an identifier but that didn't work