# MySQL how to get max count of group by time window

Tags: mysql, time-series

Say, I have 150 records spanned over 2 hours period, eg, 1am to 3pm. There are 60 records timestamped at the end of 1pm and 70 records timestamped at the beginning of the 2am.

I need to produce a report to indicate if the number of records exceeded 100 within 60 minutes, this 60 minutes period can be any 60 minutes between 1am to 2am, eg. 1:01 - 2:01, 1:13 - 2:13, 1:59-2:59 etc

```
id, created_at
...
17376889,2023-06-07 01:00:50
17376890,2023-06-07 01:00:50
17376891,2023-06-07 01:09:50
17376892,2023-06-07 01:09:50
17376901,2023-06-07 01:33:28
17376902,2023-06-07 01:33:07
17376905,2023-06-07 01:42:54
... 100+ records here
17376943,2023-06-07 02:20:57
17376944,2023-06-07 02:20:24
17376948,2023-06-07 02:20:50
17376952,2023-06-07 02:23:37
17376953,2023-06-07 02:23:37
17376954,2023-06-07 02:23:37
17376955,2023-06-07 02:23:37
17376956,2023-06-07 02:59:37
...
```

eg. in this case (1.30am - 2:30am) is it possible to get result by simply running SQL queries without involving coding? (Especially MySQL), something like this imaginary query

`SELECT max(*) as c FROM records GROUP BY PERIOD(created_at, 3600) HAVING c > 100`

If I slice by the hour to count like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599100/mysql-group-by-time), eg. 1am - 2am, 2am - 3am, I won't get any results. If I slice by the minute then I will need to aggregate by code I presume?

Comment: The `GROUP BY` expression has to include something in the rows or result set. What column does `duration(3600)` refer to?

Comment: Is `GROUP BY DATE(column), HOUR(column)` what you're looking for?

Comment: Or maybe you're looking for `WHERE column BETWEEN '01:30' AND '02:30'`? Please post some sample data and the desired results.

Comment: sorry updated question

Comment: Where's the example?

Comment: I don't understand what `DURATION(created_at, 3600)` is supposed to mean. Duration is an amount of time between two timesamps.

Comment: What does `MAX(*)` mean? You can't take the maximum of all columns at once.

Comment: `DURATION()` is my imaginary function, I want to see if there are any record count greater than 100 within 1 hour period. I changed it to `PERIOD` if it makes better sense

Comment: You want `COUNT(*) AS c ... GROUP BY HOUR(created_at) HAVING c > 100`

Comment: if I group by the `HOUR` the records will get chopped by the hour exactly like 1am-2am, 2am-3am which it won't give me the desired result.

Comment: Now I understand. I think you should be able to do this with window functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested…

```
SELECT created_at , 
    COUNT(*) OVER w AS cnt
FROM records
WINDOW w AS (
ORDER BY created_at
RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1' HOUR PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW);
```

Sources:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-named-windows.html

https://docs.sqlstream.com/glossary/sliding-window-or-rolling-wind/

Comment: Thanks the sliding window link looks very relevant.

Comment: I tried to reduce the interval to seconds, the count seems to be not working, hour and minute seems fine tho

Comment: @JamesLin please can you share the exact code snippet for the seconds?

Comment: here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77349258/mysql-sliding-window-not-returning-correct-count-if-interval-is-in-second I think I know why, see my comments

Comment: Thanks @JamesLin yep, 'BETWEEN' is always inclusive of end points. Apologies, didn't realise this was the discrepancy.

Comment: can the sliding window query be a bit more complicated eg 'intersects'?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a way to do this with window functions, but you can do it with a self-join.

```
SELECT r1.id, r1.created_at, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM records AS r1
JOIN records AS r2 ON r2.created_at BETWEEN r1.created_at AND DATE_ADD(r1.created_at, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
GROUP BY r1.id
HAVING count > 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need in something close to:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
           COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY created_at 
                          RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW 
                                    AND INTERVAL 1 HOUR FOLLOWING) cnt
    FROM tablename 
    )
SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1;
```