# MySQL sliding window not returning correct count if interval is in second

Tags: mysql

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77347893/mysql-how-to-get-max-count-of-group-by-time-window/77348270#77348270), The hour interval seems to be working fine, which gives `57`

```sql
select max(cnt) from (
        select count(*) over w as cnt from cdr
        window w as ( order by calldate range between interval '1' hour preceding and current row)
    ) as a
```

However, if I change interval to second (returns 8), the count is off, I can't find 8 records in the same second. eg.

```sql
select max(cnt) from (
        select count(*) over w as cnt from cdr
        window w as ( order by calldate range between interval '1' second preceding and current row)
    ) as a
```

Here is the DB fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eSzvJ5XyDBbHuof3SMvTV/0

Data below

```
id, id_sensor, calldate
19953276,19,2023-09-01 08:27:42
19953829,19,2023-09-01 08:34:49
19953635,19,2023-09-01 08:34:53
19954160,19,2023-09-01 08:46:19
19954829,19,2023-09-01 08:59:08
19955419,19,2023-09-01 09:06:43
19956120,19,2023-09-01 09:17:45
19956602,19,2023-09-01 09:22:54
19956656,19,2023-09-01 09:24:48
19956796,19,2023-09-01 09:26:59
19957273,19,2023-09-01 09:35:22
19958585,19,2023-09-01 09:48:11
19958251,19,2023-09-01 09:48:59
19958263,19,2023-09-01 09:49:09
19958260,19,2023-09-01 09:49:20
19958432,19,2023-09-01 09:49:47
19958711,19,2023-09-01 09:54:20
19959613,19,2023-09-01 10:07:38
19959962,19,2023-09-01 10:12:44
19960465,19,2023-09-01 10:19:24
19961472,19,2023-09-01 10:34:20
19961873,19,2023-09-01 10:34:59
19961781,19,2023-09-01 10:38:59
19962398,19,2023-09-01 10:47:36
19963384,19,2023-09-01 10:49:17
19962696,19,2023-09-01 10:51:43
19962763,19,2023-09-01 10:53:18
19963976,19,2023-09-01 11:07:12
19964382,19,2023-09-01 11:11:55
19964517,19,2023-09-01 11:12:44
19964318,19,2023-09-01 11:12:53
19964452,19,2023-09-01 11:14:00
19964870,19,2023-09-01 11:20:58
19965060,19,2023-09-01 11:23:55
19966510,19,2023-09-01 11:34:18
19966132,19,2023-09-01 11:37:51
19966527,19,2023-09-01 11:37:54
19966825,19,2023-09-01 11:45:42
19966797,19,2023-09-01 11:47:38
19966915,19,2023-09-01 11:48:51
19966916,19,2023-09-01 11:48:51
19966917,19,2023-09-01 11:48:51
19966920,19,2023-09-01 11:48:51
19966912,19,2023-09-01 11:48:52
19966919,19,2023-09-01 11:48:52
19966910,19,2023-09-01 11:48:53
19966911,19,2023-09-01 11:48:53
19966913,19,2023-09-01 11:48:53
19966914,19,2023-09-01 11:48:53
19966918,19,2023-09-01 11:48:54
19966921,19,2023-09-01 11:48:54
19966945,19,2023-09-01 11:48:55
19966953,19,2023-09-01 11:48:55
19966961,19,2023-09-01 11:48:55
19966937,19,2023-09-01 11:48:56
19966934,19,2023-09-01 11:48:57
19966935,19,2023-09-01 11:48:57
19966941,19,2023-09-01 11:48:57
19966947,19,2023-09-01 11:48:57
19966933,19,2023-09-01 11:48:59
19966940,19,2023-09-01 11:48:59
19966950,19,2023-09-01 11:48:59
19966956,19,2023-09-01 11:48:59
19966957,19,2023-09-01 11:48:59
19966954,19,2023-09-01 11:49:00
19966958,19,2023-09-01 11:49:00
19966960,19,2023-09-01 11:49:00
19966931,19,2023-09-01 11:49:01
19966942,19,2023-09-01 11:49:01
19966944,19,2023-09-01 11:49:01
19966955,19,2023-09-01 11:49:01
19966930,19,2023-09-01 11:49:02
19966951,19,2023-09-01 11:49:02
19966943,19,2023-09-01 11:49:03
19966948,19,2023-09-01 11:49:03
19966946,19,2023-09-01 11:49:04
19966952,19,2023-09-01 11:49:04
19966932,19,2023-09-01 11:49:05
19966938,19,2023-09-01 11:49:05
19966975,19,2023-09-01 11:49:05
19966976,19,2023-09-01 11:49:06
19967207,19,2023-09-01 11:52:16
19967422,19,2023-09-01 11:57:15
19967601,19,2023-09-01 11:59:36
19968537,19,2023-09-01 12:13:54
19968743,19,2023-09-01 12:15:48
19968775,19,2023-09-01 12:19:50
19968765,19,2023-09-01 12:21:24
19968824,19,2023-09-01 12:22:38
19969289,19,2023-09-01 12:31:27
19969773,19,2023-09-01 12:41:14
19970188,19,2023-09-01 12:47:22
19970954,19,2023-09-01 12:51:50
19970491,19,2023-09-01 12:53:28
19971205,19,2023-09-01 12:57:33
19971215,19,2023-09-01 13:04:48
19971226,19,2023-09-01 13:05:14
19971848,19,2023-09-01 13:14:08
19971861,19,2023-09-01 13:15:19
19972552,19,2023-09-01 13:26:57
19974451,19,2023-09-01 13:56:24
19974687,19,2023-09-01 14:00:18
19974839,19,2023-09-01 14:03:02
19974989,19,2023-09-01 14:05:13
19975221,19,2023-09-01 14:05:42
19975500,19,2023-09-01 14:08:23
19975601,19,2023-09-01 14:13:52
19976102,19,2023-09-01 14:21:41
19976301,19,2023-09-01 14:23:38
19976381,19,2023-09-01 14:25:27
19976373,19,2023-09-01 14:25:29
19976433,19,2023-09-01 14:26:06
19976901,19,2023-09-01 14:32:05
19976900,19,2023-09-01 14:32:35
19977266,19,2023-09-01 14:37:54
19977809,19,2023-09-01 14:45:25
19977916,19,2023-09-01 14:48:31
19977965,19,2023-09-01 14:48:31
19978125,19,2023-09-01 14:50:20
19979717,19,2023-09-01 15:15:56
19979865,19,2023-09-01 15:18:09
19980428,19,2023-09-01 15:26:06
19981008,19,2023-09-01 15:31:35
19981324,19,2023-09-01 15:40:48
19981813,19,2023-09-01 15:49:18
19982314,19,2023-09-01 15:58:22
19982947,19,2023-09-01 16:07:01
19982885,19,2023-09-01 16:10:39
19982956,19,2023-09-01 16:12:20
19983088,19,2023-09-01 16:12:22
19983198,19,2023-09-01 16:12:47
19983202,19,2023-09-01 16:14:10
19983554,19,2023-09-01 16:23:23
19984025,19,2023-09-01 16:35:55
19985097,19,2023-09-01 17:11:45
19988439,19,2023-09-02 09:31:25
19991840,19,2023-09-02 14:43:52
19992137,19,2023-09-02 15:24:11
19992518,19,2023-09-02 15:55:53
19992519,19,2023-09-02 15:55:53
19998549,19,2023-09-03 18:43:47
19999261,19,2023-09-04 06:07:37
20000289,19,2023-09-04 07:51:14
20001170,19,2023-09-04 08:31:21
20001206,19,2023-09-04 08:31:34
20001219,19,2023-09-04 08:32:24
20002282,19,2023-09-04 08:52:56
20003678,19,2023-09-04 09:13:54
20003952,19,2023-09-04 09:14:02
20004031,19,2023-09-04 09:19:00
20004081,19,2023-09-04 09:19:14
20004112,19,2023-09-04 09:20:04
20004646,19,2023-09-04 09:22:59
20004369,19,2023-09-04 09:23:04
20004945,19,2023-09-04 09:28:39
20004933,19,2023-09-04 09:29:36
20005976,19,2023-09-04 09:29:41
20005808,19,2023-09-04 09:42:01
20006105,19,2023-09-04 09:46:39
20006630,19,2023-09-04 09:52:48
20006995,19,2023-09-04 09:58:37
20007198,19,2023-09-04 10:00:48
20007983,19,2023-09-04 10:06:38
20007641,19,2023-09-04 10:07:23
20008037,19,2023-09-04 10:11:45
20008240,19,2023-09-04 10:15:03
20009613,19,2023-09-04 10:17:01
20008364,19,2023-09-04 10:18:31
20008358,19,2023-09-04 10:18:51
20008373,19,2023-09-04 10:19:02
20008381,19,2023-09-04 10:19:02
20008506,19,2023-09-04 10:19:31
20009123,19,2023-09-04 10:19:57
20009122,19,2023-09-04 10:21:31
20009150,19,2023-09-04 10:24:59
20009437,19,2023-09-04 10:30:32
20009765,19,2023-09-04 10:35:01
20010091,19,2023-09-04 10:38:26
20010260,19,2023-09-04 10:39:55
20010202,19,2023-09-04 10:40:56
20010234,19,2023-09-04 10:41:27
20010319,19,2023-09-04 10:42:46
20010484,19,2023-09-04 10:44:56
20010602,19,2023-09-04 10:45:45
20010703,19,2023-09-04 10:47:13
20011561,19,2023-09-04 10:59:09
20011501,19,2023-09-04 10:59:16
20011696,19,2023-09-04 11:00:32
20011678,19,2023-09-04 11:01:14
20011977,19,2023-09-04 11:06:31
20012024,19,2023-09-04 11:07:02
20012095,19,2023-09-04 11:07:17
20012173,19,2023-09-04 11:08:46
20012531,19,2023-09-04 11:09:38
20012206,19,2023-09-04 11:09:39
20012256,19,2023-09-04 11:10:15
20012422,19,2023-09-04 11:12:42
20012482,19,2023-09-04 11:13:16
20012607,19,2023-09-04 11:13:16
20012525,19,2023-09-04 11:13:38
20012501,19,2023-09-04 11:14:01
20012502,19,2023-09-04 11:14:01
20012547,19,2023-09-04 11:14:36
20012552,19,2023-09-04 11:14:37
20012619,19,2023-09-04 11:15:24
20012615,19,2023-09-04 11:15:25
20012780,19,2023-09-04 11:17:36
20012807,19,2023-09-04 11:17:53
20012850,19,2023-09-04 11:18:14
20013066,19,2023-09-04 11:18:42
20013113,19,2023-09-04 11:19:02
20012999,19,2023-09-04 11:20:13
20013029,19,2023-09-04 11:20:33
20013423,19,2023-09-04 11:24:39
20013984,19,2023-09-04 11:28:44
20013857,19,2023-09-04 11:29:20
20013829,19,2023-09-04 11:30:01
20014164,19,2023-09-04 11:30:58
20014129,19,2023-09-04 11:34:53
20014932,19,2023-09-04 11:37:21
20014411,19,2023-09-04 11:39:11
20014560,19,2023-09-04 11:40:06
20014543,19,2023-09-04 11:41:00
20014984,19,2023-09-04 11:46:56
20015186,19,2023-09-04 11:47:43
20015526,19,2023-09-04 11:49:51
20015498,19,2023-09-04 11:53:34
20015680,19,2023-09-04 11:54:26
20016225,19,2023-09-04 11:56:53
20015983,19,2023-09-04 11:57:51
20016012,19,2023-09-04 11:58:37
20016470,19,2023-09-04 11:59:05
20016413,19,2023-09-04 12:00:21
20016388,19,2023-09-04 12:05:36
20016898,19,2023-09-04 12:08:40
20016513,19,2023-09-04 12:09:47
20016653,19,2023-09-04 12:09:52
20016907,19,2023-09-04 12:16:02
20017050,19,2023-09-04 12:16:05
20017677,19,2023-09-04 12:27:30
20017603,19,2023-09-04 12:27:32
20017633,19,2023-09-04 12:27:34
20018143,19,2023-09-04 12:34:11
20018057,19,2023-09-04 12:34:42
20018235,19,2023-09-04 12:37:03
20018324,19,2023-09-04 12:39:10
20018639,19,2023-09-04 12:39:14
20018330,19,2023-09-04 12:39:56
20018834,19,2023-09-04 12:42:13
20018845,19,2023-09-04 12:44:07
20019482,19,2023-09-04 12:57:46
20019960,19,2023-09-04 13:01:30
20019995,19,2023-09-04 13:04:02
20020445,19,2023-09-04 13:08:08
20020800,19,2023-09-04 13:14:40
20021371,19,2023-09-04 13:19:12
20021533,19,2023-09-04 13:25:57
20022276,19,2023-09-04 13:30:36
20022311,19,2023-09-04 13:31:48
20023454,19,2023-09-04 13:48:35
20023455,19,2023-09-04 13:48:35
20023970,19,2023-09-04 13:50:37
20023774,19,2023-09-04 13:55:51
20023931,19,2023-09-04 13:58:01
20024289,19,2023-09-04 14:00:32
20025020,19,2023-09-04 14:02:47
20024962,19,2023-09-04 14:07:03
20024856,19,2023-09-04 14:08:20
20024858,19,2023-09-04 14:08:40
20025031,19,2023-09-04 14:08:59
20024822,19,2023-09-04 14:09:37
20025143,19,2023-09-04 14:13:55
20025377,19,2023-09-04 14:19:11
20025541,19,2023-09-04 14:21:40
20025546,19,2023-09-04 14:21:59
20026140,19,2023-09-04 14:31:32
20026417,19,2023-09-04 14:35:18
20027070,19,2023-09-04 14:37:46
20027306,19,2023-09-04 14:47:26
20027361,19,2023-09-04 14:48:25
20027393,19,2023-09-04 14:48:58
20028433,19,2023-09-04 15:01:52
20028450,19,2023-09-04 15:03:04
20028434,19,2023-09-04 15:03:34
20028872,19,2023-09-04 15:07:29
20028849,19,2023-09-04 15:08:07
20029242,19,2023-09-04 15:13:52
20029256,19,2023-09-04 15:14:34
20029321,19,2023-09-04 15:17:12
20029798,19,2023-09-04 15:18:21
20030072,19,2023-09-04 15:28:31
20030073,19,2023-09-04 15:28:33
20030156,19,2023-09-04 15:28:53
20030587,19,2023-09-04 15:30:26
20032050,19,2023-09-04 15:56:36
20031710,19,2023-09-04 15:56:46
20032375,19,2023-09-04 16:00:35
20032768,19,2023-09-04 16:13:11
20032837,19,2023-09-04 16:15:03
20032887,19,2023-09-04 16:15:27
20033034,19,2023-09-04 16:18:28
20033049,19,2023-09-04 16:18:59
20033293,19,2023-09-04 16:19:43
20033298,19,2023-09-04 16:21:35
20033988,19,2023-09-04 16:21:44
20033483,19,2023-09-04 16:24:11
20033855,19,2023-09-04 16:30:48
20035534,19,2023-09-04 17:25:00
20035714,19,2023-09-04 17:36:08
20035682,19,2023-09-04 17:36:09
20035706,19,2023-09-04 17:36:09
20035708,19,2023-09-04 17:36:09
20035713,19,2023-09-04 17:36:09
20035695,19,2023-09-04 17:36:10
20035698,19,2023-09-04 17:36:10
20035709,19,2023-09-04 17:36:10
20035683,19,2023-09-04 17:36:11
20035691,19,2023-09-04 17:36:11
20035705,19,2023-09-04 17:36:11
20035711,19,2023-09-04 17:36:11
20035689,19,2023-09-04 17:36:13
20035693,19,2023-09-04 17:36:13
20035702,19,2023-09-04 17:36:13
20035704,19,2023-09-04 17:36:13
20035687,19,2023-09-04 17:36:14
20035716,19,2023-09-04 17:36:14
20035703,19,2023-09-04 17:36:15
20035718,19,2023-09-04 17:36:15
20035685,19,2023-09-04 17:36:16
20035710,19,2023-09-04 17:36:16
20035692,19,2023-09-04 17:36:17
20035697,19,2023-09-04 17:36:17
20035699,19,2023-09-04 17:36:17
20035707,19,2023-09-04 17:36:17
20035684,19,2023-09-04 17:36:18
20035715,19,2023-09-04 17:36:18
20035717,19,2023-09-04 17:36:18
20035688,19,2023-09-04 17:36:19
20035694,19,2023-09-04 17:36:19
20035700,19,2023-09-04 17:36:19
20035696,19,2023-09-04 17:36:20
20035712,19,2023-09-04 17:36:20
20035681,19,2023-09-04 17:36:21
20035686,19,2023-09-04 17:36:21
20035690,19,2023-09-04 17:36:21
20035701,19,2023-09-04 17:36:21
20035720,19,2023-09-04 17:36:22
20035721,19,2023-09-04 17:36:22
20035722,19,2023-09-04 17:36:23
20035723,19,2023-09-04 17:36:23
20036310,19,2023-09-04 18:26:29
```

Comment: Oh... is it because it's boundary inclusive, so that `01:00:00 0000` and `01:00:01 0000` are the treated same second interval? If that's the case then yes I could see 8 records that fit in the criteria.

Comment: It does seem it's inclusive, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between would love to have some experts to confirm this is actually the case to cause it to return `8`

Comment: *I can't find 8 records in the same second* Not in the same only but in the same and in the previous! 3 rows with `2023-09-01 11:49:00` + 5 rows with `2023-09-01 11:48:59` in your fiddle.

Comment: yes that's what I was suspecting, because boundaries are inclusive, so 3 rows + 5 rows like you said counted in 1 second interval.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the interval to less than one second and returned 5, should prove the boundary inclusive theory.

```sql
select max(cnt) from (
        select count(*) over w as cnt from cdr
        window w as ( order by calldate range between interval '999999' microsecond preceding and current row)
    ) as a
```