# Selecting max price from every 5 rows

Tags: mysql

I've been trying and trying and haven't been able to figure this out.

In stock charts that have Open, High, Low, Close, you can always chart every minute, 5 min, 10 min, hour, etc. I have data for every minute and I'm trying to select out the Open, High, Low, Close from that minute-by-minute data, but for every 5 minutes.

I have data similar to this:

```
__________________________________________________
| Date     | TIME    | TICKER  | Open  | High  | Low   | Close |
| 20121203 | 090000  |  QQQQ   | 23.54 | 24.12 | 23.01 | 23.24 |
| 20121203 | 090100  |  QQQQ   | 23.24 | 24.14 | 22.98 | 24.13 |
| 20121203 | 090200  |  QQQQ   | 24.13 | 25.88 | 23.75 | 25.81 |
| 20121203 | 090300  |  QQQQ   | 25.81 | 25.83 | 24.63 | 24.99 |
| 20121203 | 090400  |  QQQQ   | 24.99 | 25.21 | 23.89 | 24.12 |
| 20121203 | 090500  |  QQQQ   | 24.12 | 24.19 | 21.94 | 22.03 |
| 20121203 | 090600  |  QQQQ   | 22.03 | 22.97 | 20.68 | 21.44 |
| 20121203 | 090700  |  QQQQ   | 21.44 | 24.06 | 19.32 | 23.56 |
| 20121203 | 090800  |  QQQQ   | 23.56 | 25.48 | 23.07 | 25.01 |
| 20121203 | 090900  |  QQQQ   | 25.01 | 28.00 | 24.18 | 27.21 |
| 20121203 | 091000  |  QQQQ   | 27.21 | 27.55 | 24.31 | 24.31 |
```

I need to grab the max(high) for the rows that have a time >= 090000 (that's 9 a.m.) 09 hours 00 minutes 00 seconds.

Similar to this, I need min(low), and then I'll grab the close price when time is 090400 because I'm getting every 5 minutes. I could also use the open of the next 5 minute increment, so that's flexible.

I've used nested SELECT statements, multiple joins, etc. The problem is that the MySQL execution time is about 1 second per row returned. That's crazy slow when you figure there are 12 rows per hour (60 minutes / 5 minutes = 12), and then because I'm actually doing FOREX, the trading is around the clock, so 24 hours. That gives me 288 per day, or just under 5 minutes per day. To do 1 year of data (~ 250 trading days) would be about 20 hours. There has to be a faster way.

I've got some solutions for this with the ID being continuous, and though that might be easiest, I'm not 100% sure my data would be correct in doing that. The reason why is that on Fridays the trading day ends at normal business hours in NY and opens up with the first trading in Tokyo (about mid-afternoon in the United States).

I've looked at GROUP BY, but I'm not sure how I can group the data to get a group of 5 where the time is within 5 minutes of each 5 minute group.

Thanks for your thoughts and discussion.

Jarod

Comment: Smells like [Grouping into interval of 5 minutes within a time range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range)

Comment: Could you show us a sample query output?

Comment: I'm not sure about a sample query output. @njk - how do I group in to intervals of 5 minutes within a time range? I agree that this sounds like it should work, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @j_allen_morris did you follow the link?

Comment: Ha! @nkj - sorry, didn't see that you posted a link. Idiot -->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should show max(high) and min(low) for every 5 minutes

```
SELECT Max(high), 
       Min(low) 
FROM   tbl 
GROUP  BY ROUND(Unix_timestamp(Date(Concat(`date`, `time`))) / ( 5 * 60 ))
```

In the Group by clause we concat your date time column. So it forms something like `20121203090000`. This is one the format that is recognized as date in mysql. So we pass it to `date()` function. Then its converted to `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`. Its divided by 5 mins timespan. The result will be a *float* value. But we require same value for a specific time span. Hence the `ROUND()`.  It makes the floating value to the nearest integer. To understand how its working run this query.

```
SELECT high, 
       low 
       Unix_timestamp(Date(Concat(`date`, `time`))) / ( 5 * 60 ) `5-min span`
       ROUND(Unix_timestamp(Date(Concat(`date`, `time`))) / ( 5 * 60 )) `5-min span rounded`
FROM   tbl
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more of what is going on in the GROUP BY section?

Comment: here is what worked for me
`SELECT max(high), FLOOR(round(\`time\`/500,1)) as theGroup FROM \`2011\` WHERE date = 20110103 GROUP BY theGroup`

Comment: This will only work if your date is fixed (`where date = ..`). Otherwise it'll match time from older dates too. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Also, I had issues when I took out the date. I took out the date because I wanted it to group it by date and give me results for every date in the table I have (which holds one year of data).  Here is what worked:

`SELECT max(high), Concat(\`date\`,FLOOR(round(\`time\`/500,1))) as theGroup FROM \`2011\` GROUP BY theGroup`

This groups the time to give the first 5 rows a value of 0, then the next 5 rows a value of 1, etc. The problem was that each day had the same numbers so I used Concat() to add the date and group by so it worked. Even though each date had a 0 up through 288

Comment: [conintued...]
(24 hours x 12 groups of 5 per hour), it now was 201101030, 201101031, 201101032, etc. and the next day was 201101040, 201101041, 201101043, etc. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: My time isn't in seconds.  It's in minutes. That's why / 500 rather than / 300

Comment: Your time is in `HHiiss` format where all `ss` are `00`. if the column is integer then dividing by 500 will also work. Otherwise you might encounter slow performance.

Comment: I've ran it a few hours ago and no performance issues.  Took just over 1 second for 73,544 records. AMAZING! If I could vote your response again, I would.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> SELECT CONCAT(DATE,SUBSTRING(`Time`,1,2),"["
>         ,IF(SUBSTRING(`Time`,4,1)<5,CONCAT(SUBSTRING(`Time`,3,1),"0"),CONCAT(SUBSTRING(`Time`,3,1),"5"))
>         ,"-"
>         ,IF(SUBSTRING(`Time`,4,1)<5,CONCAT(SUBSTRING(`Time`,3,1),"5"),CONCAT(SUBSTRING(`Time`,3,1)+1,"0"))
>         ,"]") AS timeStr    ,MAX(High)  ,MIN(LOW) FROM tb1 GROUP BY timeStr;

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b748/1

Comment: I posted in the comments above what worked for me. Thanks for the answer!