# Grouping Data with Flot Charts

Tags: javascript, mysql, flot

**Scenario:** I'm plotting a volume bar chart using Flot JS, with a per-minute data. So for example, for 3 hours, I have 3 x 60 data points being pulled from the database.

**Problem:** Since there I have 6 hours worth of data points, and the width of the chart is only 250px, the bars are only 1px wide each, without margins. I was wondering if there's a grouping data option in Flot Charts where I could tell it to average the volume data per 15 minutes or 30 minutes.

```
$.plot('#flot-vol, [{
    color: '#fff',
    bars: { show: true },
    data: dataV
}], {
    grid: { show: false },
    shadowSize: false
});
```

In High Charts there is a GroupData option wherein you can group the given data by day / week / months. I was wondering if there's such a feature in Flot Charts?

If I need to use MySQL to group the data, how do I group the data per 30 minutes if I have the following MySQL statement? Currently I'm pulling all the volume of the latest date from the table named Ticker.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`Timestamp`), `Volume` from `Ticker` WHERE CompID = 'symbol' AND Date(`Timestamp`) = (SELECT Max(Date(`Timestamp`)) FROM `Ticker`)
```

---

Update:

Thanks to Ryley for clarifying the answer, in case anyone is wondering how to group the data through MySQL, here it is.
**MySQL Statement that Worked**

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`Timestamp`), AVG(`Volume`) FROM `Ticker` WHERE `CompID` = 'symbol' AND Date(`Timestamp`) = (SELECT Max(Date(`Timestamp`)) FROM `Ticker`) GROUP BY (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`Timestamp`) DIV 30*60)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flot does not aggregate data itself, but you're on the right track thinking about doing it from mysql.

Make your query average the data into 30 minute segments:

```
SELECT trunc(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`Timestamp`)/(30*60))*(30*60) as time_chunk, 
       AVG(`Volume`) from `Ticker` 
WHERE CompID = 'symbol' AND 
      Date(`Timestamp`) = (SELECT Max(Date(`Timestamp`)) FROM `Ticker`)
GROUP BY time_chunk
```

I'm not a MySQL user, so this may not be exactly right, but the idea is to take your timestamp and truncate it to 30 minute increments, then average the Volume over that 30 minutes.

Comment: thanks for clarifying that out! As for the MySQL syntax, I found a similar question in another [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range)

I'll edit my post of what worked for me :)