# Get elements by two hour range in ruby / rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

I have a ton of events coming from PostreSQL database, I would like to group them by two hour range and give the first one parameter `visible=true`

What would be the most efficient way of choosing these items?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range

Comment: What do you mean by "group them" and "first one" and "give parameter visible = true"?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4345308/712765