# Get transactions balance for each month

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a 2 column table with transactions where time of change (unix_time) and change value is stored.

```
create table transactions (    
  changed int(11),
  points int(11)
);

insert into transactions values (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-03-27 03:00:00'), +100);
insert into transactions values (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-05-02 03:00:00'), +100);
insert into transactions values (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01 03:00:00'), -100);
insert into transactions values (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-05-01 03:00:00'), +150);
```

To get current balance you need to sum all values and to get balance from the past you need to sum if change time for this value is less then requested like:

```
select 
    sum(case when changed < unix_timestamp('2013-12-01') then 
            points 
        else 
            0 
        end) as cash_balance_2013_11,
...
```

so for each month there need to be a separate SQL code. I would like to have SQL code that will give me balances for all months. (eg from fixed date till now)

EDIT:

[HERE IS SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08215/7)

Comment: You could group into intervals as here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range

Comment: @ Horst Walter: As far as I can imagine this will give me changes during one month. To get the balance you need to sum all previous values not only from given month.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just `group by` and `order by` month?

**UPDATE:** to get running totals you have to join the individual months to a set of totals-by-month, matching on "less than or equal to":-

```
select
     m.single_month
   , sum(month_of_change.total_points)  as running total_by_month
from
(
   select 
        sum(points) as total_points
      , month_of_change
   from 
   (
   select 
        points
      , MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(t.time_of_change)) as month_of_change -- assumes unix_time
   from mytable t
   ) x
   group by month_of_change 
) monthly_totals
inner join
(
   select distinct MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(t.time_of_change)) as single_month
) m
on monthly_totals.month_of_change <= m.single_month
group by m.single_month
```

(N.B: not tested)

Comment: As far as I can imagine this will give me changes during one month. To get the balance you need to sum all previous values not only from given month.

Comment: Interesting, but my brain overflown after 3rd subquery, so I need to check this. I cant vote you up as I do not have enough reputation, sorry.

Comment: I was not able to make it work. I updated my question to make it more clear.