# RethinkDB - How to group on aggregated time intervals

Tags: aggregate, rethinkdb

I'd like to group and average on dynamic time intervals. Similar question to: [Grouping into interval of 5 minutes within a time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range).

Right now, I am using the query:

```
r.db('windMachine').table('stats3')
  .between(r.time(2015, 5, 7, 18, 0, 0, "Z"), r.time(2015, 5, 7, 24, 0, 0, "Z"), {index: "date"})
  .group([r.row("date").hours(), r.row("date").minutes()])
  .avg("TMP0")
```

Which returns:

```
[
  {
    "group": [
      21,
      2
    ],
    "reduction": 22.802153846153846
  },
  {
    "group": [
      21,
      3
    ],
    "reduction": 22.6628
  },
  {
    "group": [
      21,
      4
    ],
    "reduction": 22.384324324324318
  }
]
```

I'd like to group this further, down into 5 minute (or other) intervals. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually met a similar problem and here is what I did:

```
.group(r.row('date').toEpochTime().sub(r.row('date').toEpochTime().mod(<INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS>))
```

What this do is to group time by `<INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS>`

I don't know if this is the best way for the task but it works for me.

Comment: This works for me as well, thank you! I wonder if it is the most performant way to do this, though.

Comment: RethinkDB currently does not support `floor` nor `ceil`, so I think this is the best I can get.

Comment: RethinkDB now supports `floor`, which you'll need to truncate the decimal places in the epoch time.