# Combining items into interval bins by timestamps

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is basically what I need to do but I'm not working with a table so I need to do it in Ruby/Rails or even Javascript. The data is returned from an external call that's a bit slow so I'm trying to format the data as quickly as possible. There could be up to thousands of elements.

I get this input:

```
{"data": [
            {"time": "2015-04-01 05:10","count": 1},
            {"time": "2015-04-01 06:00","count": 3},
            {"time": "2015-04-01 06:50","count": 2},
            {"time": "2015-04-01 07:40","count": 8},
            {"time": "2015-04-01 07:48","count": 5}
        ]
}
```

And want to return something like this(with 1 hr buckets):

```
{"buckets": [
              {"time": "2015-04-01 05:00", "count": 1},
              {"time": "2015-04-01 06:00", "count": 5},
              {"time": "2015-04-01 07:00", "count": 13}
            ]
}
```

The only thing I can think of to do is use a bunch of if's and iterate through adding to the count if the hour === last.hour else create a new element if it's different. It feels like there must be a more elegant solution though.

I can't seem to find a nice solution in Ruby/Javascript. This is the same idea but none of this is in my db.
[Grouping into interval of 5 minutes within a time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range)

If I want the user to be able to select to view the data by hour, day, week, etc. Is this the best strategy?

Comment: Both are great answers. I accepted the answer which saves me from having to format the date back to the input format. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Round the time down to its hour and build up a new hash with the aggregate counts. If you want the user to select a time period, just pick the `strftime` format based on the bucket size. You could do math on the `Time` object, but you're going to format it anyway, so may as well do it there. Since you're in Rails, you can also use the `Time#beginning_of_*` methods.

Here's a script that will do it if your data is in `data.json`:

```
require 'json'
require 'time'

data = JSON.parse(File.read('data.json'))['data']

result = Hash.new(0) # Missing entries get initialized to 0

data.each do |entry|
  time = Time.parse(entry['time'])
  hour = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00') # Effectively round to the hour
  result[hour] += entry['count']
end

result_list = result.map do |time, count|
  {time: time, count: count}
end
puts JSON.pretty_generate(buckets: result_list)
```

Output:

```
$ ruby group.rb
{
  "buckets": [
    { "time": "2015-04-01 05:00", "count": 1 },
    { "time": "2015-04-01 06:00", "count": 5 },
    { "time": "2015-04-01 07:00", "count": 13 }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Rails using [`beginning_of_hour`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/Time/beginning_of_hour) you can group times together like this:

```
a = [
     {"time"=>"2015-04-01 05:10","count"=>1},
     {"time"=>"2015-04-01 06:00","count"=>3},
     {"time"=>"2015-04-01 06:50","count"=>2},
     {"time"=>"2015-04-01 07:40","count"=>8},        
     {"time"=>"2015-04-01 07:48","count"=>5}                     
    ] 

hash = Hash.new(0)
a.each{ |k|
  hash[k["time"].to_time.beginning_of_hour] += k["count"]
}

hash.map{|k,v| {"time" => k, "count" => v}}
# => [{"time"=>2015-04-01 05:00:00 UTC, "count"=>1}, {"time"=>2015-04-01 06:00:00 UTC, "count"=>5}, {"time"=>2015-04-01 07:00:00 UTC, "count"=>13}]
```