# Trying to get 3 hours of data from SQL displayed per 5 minutes

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a date_of_post column in my table which looks like this (example) `2015-08-31 11:00:00`

I use the `INTERVAL 1 DAY` to get the last 24 hours and it works great.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(date(t.date_of_post), INTERVAL hour(t.date_of_post)  HOUR)  AS dateTime, count(*) as entries
        FROM `soc_stat` t
        WHERE main_tag = 'coffee' AND t.date_of_post > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
        GROUP BY date(t.date_of_post), hour(t.date_of_post)
```

However now I would like to get the last 3 hours returned by per 5 minutes. So it would return something along the lines of

```
2015-08-31 12:05:00 = 11
2015-08-31 13:10:00 = 23
2015-08-31 14:15:00 = 7
2015-08-31 15:20:00 = 12
```

I am not very strong in SQL. I tried changing `INTERVAL hour(t.date_of_post)  HOUR` to `INTERVAL minute(t.date_of_post)  MINUTE` and then I changed the `INTERVAL 1 DAY` to `INTERVAL 1 HOUR`. I thought that would return entries by minutes instead of hours, but appears it did not. And then I would have tried to figure out how to get it to return per 5 minutes instead of by every minute.

How would I go about getting all the entries from the last 3 hours by every 5 minute?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grouping into interval of 5 minutes within a time range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following query will give you data of every 5 min interval.

You may add filter in `where clause` as per your requirement.

```
SELECT 
DATE_ADD(date(t.date_of_post), INTERVAL hour(t.date_of_post)*60+(minute(t.date_of_post) div 5)*5  MINUTE)  AS dateTime,
count(*) as entries
        FROM `soc_stat` t

        GROUP BY date(t.date_of_post), hour(t.date_of_post),minute(t.date_of_post) div 5
```