# "Online" entries in each 5 minutes

Tags: postgresql

I have this movimentations table:

```
| id | user_id | in_time             | out_time            |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 152     | 2015-08-28 15:43:00 | 2015-08-28 15:50:00 |        
| 2  | 123     | 2015-08-28 15:44:00 | 2015-08-28 15:55:00 |        
| 3  | 156     | 2015-08-28 15:50:00 | (null)              |        
| 4  | 211     | 2015-08-28 16:00:00 | 2015-08-28 16:17:00 |        
| 5  | 176     | 2015-08-28 16:21:00 | (null)              |
```

I need to know how many users were online each five minutes (15:40, 15:45, 15:50 and so on) to plot a graph. This is not the same problem they solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range), because here I have an in_time and a out_time, which leds me to count how much "online" entries. I know how to do it easly by using mutiple queries:

```
SELECT * FROM movimentations WHERE out_time > '2015-08-28 15:40:00' AND in_time < '2015-08-28 15:40:00' UNION 
SELECT * FROM movimentations WHERE out_time > '2015-08-28 15:45:00' AND in_time < '2015-08-28 15:45:00' UNION 
SELECT * FROM movimentations WHERE out_time > '2015-08-28 15:50:00' AND in_time < '2015-08-28 15:50:00' UNION 
SELECT * FROM movimentations WHERE out_time > '2015-08-28 15:55:00' AND in_time < '2015-08-28 15:55:00';
```

But of course I'm looking for a better solution. Is there a way to do it in a single query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grouping into interval of 5 minutes within a time range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range)

Comment: @SterlingArcher, unfortunately, this is not. My problem lies on having in_time and out_time, and that's not solved there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query generates the `timepoints`:

```
select t
from generate_series('2015-08-28 15:40:00', '2015-08-28 16:30:00', '5m'::interval) t

           t            
------------------------
 2015-08-28 15:40:00+02
 2015-08-28 15:45:00+02
 2015-08-28 15:50:00+02
 2015-08-28 15:55:00+02
 2015-08-28 16:00:00+02
 2015-08-28 16:05:00+02
 2015-08-28 16:10:00+02
 2015-08-28 16:15:00+02
 2015-08-28 16:20:00+02
 2015-08-28 16:25:00+02
 2015-08-28 16:30:00+02
(11 rows)
```

If you `cross join` this dataset with `movimentations` and filter rows, you'll obtain:

```
with timepoints as (
    select t
    from generate_series('2015-08-28 15:40:00', '2015-08-28 16:30:00', '5m'::interval) t
    )
select t, count(*)
from movimentations
cross join timepoints
where in_time <= t and coalesce(out_time, 'infinity') >= t
group by 1
order by 1;

           t            | count 
------------------------+-------
 2015-08-28 15:45:00+02 |     2
 2015-08-28 15:50:00+02 |     3
 2015-08-28 15:55:00+02 |     2
 2015-08-28 16:00:00+02 |     2
 2015-08-28 16:05:00+02 |     2
 2015-08-28 16:10:00+02 |     2
 2015-08-28 16:15:00+02 |     2
 2015-08-28 16:20:00+02 |     1
 2015-08-28 16:25:00+02 |     2
 2015-08-28 16:30:00+02 |     2
(10 rows)
```

This result does not contain *empty* `timepoints`. If you want to have them you should `left join` timespoints with the result set:

```
with timepoints as (
    select t
    from generate_series('2015-08-28 15:40:00', '2015-08-28 16:30:00', '5m'::interval) t
    )
select t.t, c.count
from timepoints t
left join (
    select t, count(*)
    from movimentations
    cross join timepoints t
    where in_time <= t and coalesce(out_time, 'infinity') >= t
    group by 1
    order by 1
    ) c on c.t = t.t;

           t            | count 
------------------------+-------
 2015-08-28 15:40:00+02 |      
 2015-08-28 15:45:00+02 |     2
 2015-08-28 15:50:00+02 |     3
 2015-08-28 15:55:00+02 |     2
 2015-08-28 16:00:00+02 |     2
 2015-08-28 16:05:00+02 |     2
 2015-08-28 16:10:00+02 |     2
 2015-08-28 16:15:00+02 |     2
 2015-08-28 16:20:00+02 |     1
 2015-08-28 16:25:00+02 |     2
 2015-08-28 16:30:00+02 |     2
(11 rows)
```

Comment: This does work! Didn't know this "generate_series". Thanks ;)