# Minutely/Hourly data PHP or SQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have this column (datetime type)

```
Begin time
===================
2015-12-04 00:00:06
2015-12-04 00:00:09
2015-12-04 00:00:10
2015-12-04 00:00:13
2015-12-04 00:00:18
2015-12-04 00:00:22
2015-12-04 00:00:33
2015-12-04 00:00:47
2015-12-04 00:01:00
2015-12-05 00:01:00
2015-12-05 00:01:07
2015-12-06 00:01:09
2015-12-06 00:01:11
2015-12-06 00:01:32
2015-12-06 00:01:34
2015-12-07 00:02:00
2015-12-07 00:02:59
```

How to get minutely/hourly data from the column and group it like this:

```
Time                 | Count
00:00:00 - 00:00:59  | 8
00:01:00 - 00:01:59  | 7
00:02:00 - 00:02:59  | 2
00:03:00 - 00:03:59  | 0
...
23:59:00 - 23:59:59  | 0
```

I think it's differrent with [Grouping into interval of 5 minutes within a time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range) because i need to get all the data from each of date and sum it into 1 column. 
for example, there are two similar data in my column with different date

```
Begin time
================
2015-12-05 00:01:00
2015-12-06 00:01:09
```

From this data, I need the data output like :

```
Time                 | Count
00:00:00 - 00:00:59  | 0
00:01:00 - 00:01:59  | 2
00:02:00 - 00:02:59  | 0
00:03:00 - 00:03:59  | 0
...
23:59:00 - 23:59:59  | 0
```

Thank you very much for all your help fellas!

Comment: change all of those `.` to `-` so you can use mysql date functions natively on that column without any conversion. then you can use `group by date_format(time, '%H')` to group it by the hour then order it by the minute with `order by date_format(time, '%i');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grouping into interval of 5 minutes within a time range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `DATE_FORMAT` and `GROUP BY` to get that:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FROMAT(col_date, '%H:%m:00 - %H:%m:59') AS `Time`,
    COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM ..
GROUP BY `Time`
```

Comment: I still can't get the summary of all the date , but thanks btw, appreciate it so much

Comment: If you need all dates, even without any rows, you need to generated all minutes first, even there is no item for them.

Comment: I actually have generated all the minutes with some functions, i'll show and close this question because some people will think it looks similar with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range :3