# Building an uptime graph from a list of heartbeats in PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, graph, charts

I have a number of devices that "check in" once a minute, i.e. a heartbeat. These heartbeats are stored in a table in MySQL as follows:

```
+----+-----------+---------------------+
| id | entity_id |      heartbeat      |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
| 1  | xyz       | 2016-01-01 01:02:03 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
```

The "id" column is an auto-incrementing integer, the "entity_id" basically identifies the device, and the "heartbeat" column is the timestamp when the device checked in. All well and good.

Now, I'd like to use JavaScript (specifically Chart.js) to create a nice uptime chart that shows how much of the last week the device was up (i.e. sending a heartbeat).

The problem I have is that obviously I only store the timestamps when the device checks in. So say it doesn't check in for 30 minutes, there will be a gap of 30 minutes between the two timestamps I **do** have.

I'm using PHP on the server side. Is there any easy method of using this list of timestamps to create maybe a JSON object that shows, every minute, whether or not there was a timestamp? I can then feed this into Chart.js to show the data as a bar chart.

Bearing in mind that this table has hundreds of thousands of rows, I'm also trying to make it relatively quick to get the data out.

Comment: what kind of device you're talking about?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to have a data point like 0 or 1, for every minute for every device for an entire week? That would mean a JSON of 10k data points per device. I think you should reconsider thinking in terms of individual data points but rather group them into segments of uptime and downtime.

Comment: @heximal They're tablets that check in every minute so that I can tell if they're online

Comment: If you have hundreds of thousands of rows, it would seem to me that you'd be better served doing several layers of pre-parsing before sending a json object: First, for what time range? This alone will help reduce the amount of data being sent.  Second, how do you intend to "show the chart", specifically? Parsing the data down to - say - show ONLY those time periods where there was downtime, would also help reduce the amount of data being sent.  Then javascript's job can be greatly simplified.

Comment: @apriede Yes that's right, but I'll only be showing the uptime for one device at any one time, so yes, around 10,000 data points

Comment: @cale_b There are many rows in the database itself, but I select only the rows for one device for a week, so a full set of heartbeats will be just over 10,000 rows. However, it is unlikely that there will be a full set, with ones missing here and there. I want to detect the absence of a heartbeat as well as the presence of one.

Comment: I don't know what kind of data format Chart.js takes, but I would just query the timestamps for one device and then loop through them and check if subsequent rows have a time difference of say 1.5min to maybe allow for some delay and create an array of segments with two points- uptime_start and uptime_end. Then you would only need to send those segments which would include all the data points in between. So you could draw lines of uptime and not individual points. Maybe can even be done by SQL but I can't think of anything now. This will greatly decrease the size of your JSON string.

Comment: i think it will be worthwhile to research if you can fix this with a query to group by per minute but also show a 0 for the empty values i think what you want to achief can be done with something simular like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range so no need to create functions and make it more difficult you will have every minute selected with either a 1 or 0 to indicate if its present or not

Comment: @lauw Yes, I also saw that as you were commenting! I can now get groups sets of uptime, all I need to work out as you say is how to get MySQL to fill in the gaps with zeros...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a query like the one in [Grouping into interval of 5 minutes within a time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range) for MySQL. Then, in JavaScript, I used Moment.js to get a time in the past, and a loop to go around adding 5 minutes and checking to see if a matching record can be found from the database.

SQL:

```
select unix_timestamp(date_format(`heartbeat`, \'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i\')) as `timestamp`,
count(`heartbeat`) as `num_heartbeats` from `table`
where `entity_id` = ? and `heartbeat` >= <date one week ago>
group by unix_timestamp(`heartbeat`) div 300, `entity_id`
order by `id` asc
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$.get('/ajax/site/uptime', { entity_id: entity_id })
.done(function(data) {
    var heartbeats = [];

    // Get the time now and 7 days ago
    var date = moment().subtract(7, 'days').startOf('hour');
    var now = moment();

    // Find the number of heartbeats per five minutes and add to the array
    do
    {
        if (data[date.format('X')] !== undefined)
        {
            heartbeats.push(1);
        }
        else
        {
            heartbeats.push(0);
        }

        date.add(5, 'minutes');
    }
    while (date.format('X') <= now.format('X'));
});
```