# Group and sum rows in a table with historical data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with data entry regarding the activity of an RFID reader. It has data being inserted every second. I want to write a query to sum the ping_count of the rows with the same item_id & antenna_id at an interval of 5 seconds.

My question is how do we group rows of table starting from one value to another value, in intervals of 5 seconds. (if there is no data to be placed for that 5 seconds, then there need no be an entry for that).

Comment: Check this question [Grouping into interval of 5 minutes within a time range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range/4345308#4345308)

Answer (score 0):

Such expression will give you interval start point

```
floor(time_in_seconds/5)*5
```

Then you can group by it