# Grouping data into 5 minute time intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can you group a column by 5 minute time intervals? For example:

```
Date_Timing                    team
---------------------------------------         
2016-10-16-10:32:08            baseball            
2016-10-16-10:34:11            baseball             
2016-10-16-10:35:12            baseball              
2016-10-16-10:41:14            Soccer              
2016-10-16-10:43:15            soccer            
2016-10-16-10:44:19            soccer
```

and results is supposed to be as;

```
team   
-------- 
baseball   
soccer           
Soccer
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which database you use?

Comment: Which database do you use? MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQL Server or any other?

Comment: MS SQL 2014 management studio

Comment: I'm confused as the three baseball records are more that 5 seconds apart - they are roughly 2 and 1 minute apart, respectively.

Comment: Are you using different rows for `soccer` and `Soccer` due to the casing or the timing?

Comment: No the same column

Comment: Are you looking for somethnig similar to these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range

Comment: do you mean 5 minues or 5 seconds ?

Comment: And how will you base the starting times? Are you certain that the first item in the set is good enough? It's much more common to work with canonical time ranges (ie ranges that start at :00, :05, :10, :15, :20 etc).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT team
FROM table_name
WHERE Date_Timing BETWEEN DATEADD('ss',-5,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY team
```

this will get last 5 seconds records and group by team

Comment: It is returning no row

Comment: Msg 1023, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Invalid parameter 1 specified for dateadd.

Comment: it is not grouping by every 5 seconds

Comment: ok, is there error or no rows and if error what is the err? please be quick I need to go and I don't wanna leave you in the middle of it.

Comment: change _ss_ to _dd_

Comment: shows all the entry but not grouping by every 5 seconds

Comment: this is because there is NO DATA for the last 5 seconds _dd_ used for days, this results is for the last 5 days, if you have data inserted to table dynamically, it will work by _ss_ (seconds), thank you.

Comment: @Abood, I think your response is not what Chelsea is asking for. There's no specifications regarding showing only data of the last x seconds (it requires a constantly updated table to display anything at all) and furthermore the sample data has a time span of over 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can as the below:

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (Date_Timing DATETIME, team VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @Tbl
VALUES
('2016-10-16 10:32:08', 'baseball'),            
('2016-10-16 10:34:11', 'baseball'),             
('2016-10-16 10:35:12', 'baseball'),              
('2016-10-16 10:41:14', 'Soccer'),              
('2016-10-16 10:43:15', 'soccer'),            
('2016-10-16 10:44:19', 'soccer')


;WITH CTE1 AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date_Timing) AS RowId FROM @Tbl ),
CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT 
        A.Date_Timing ,
        A.team,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MIN(B.RowId)) [Group]
    FROM 
        CTE1 A CROSS JOIN CTE1 B
    WHERE 
        ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, A.Date_Timing, B.Date_Timing)) BETWEEN 0 AND 5 -- 5 min
    GROUP BY 
        A.Date_Timing ,
        A.team  
)

SELECT
    A.team COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AS team   
FROM
    CTE2 A
GROUP BY
    A.team COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS,
    A.[Group]
```

Result:

```
team
----------------
baseball
Soccer
soccer
```

Answer (score 0):

Grouping by 5 minutes time interval much depends on the start of the first interval slot. You can group by the minutes from SQL Server epoch divided by 5 like in the example below

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (Date_Timing DATETIME, team VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @Tbl
VALUES
('2016-10-16 10:32:08', 'baseball'),            
('2016-10-16 10:34:11', 'baseball'),             
('2016-10-16 10:35:12', 'baseball'),              
('2016-10-16 10:41:14', 'Soccer'),              
('2016-10-16 10:43:15', 'soccer'),            
('2016-10-16 10:44:19', 'soccer')

DECLARE @start_interval datetime
SET @start_interval = '00:01'

select 
  team COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS as team,
  DATEADD(MINUTE,5*floor(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@start_interval,Date_Timing)/5),@start_interval) as time_interval 
from @Tbl 
group by team COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as, 
    floor(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@start_interval,Date_Timing)/5)
```

@start_interval set to '00:01' means that we start interval from the first minute after SQL Server epoch, so according to your data the slots will be 10:31-10:35:59.999, 10:36-10:40:59.999, 10:41-10:45:59.999 and so on. Try to set the start period as you like.