# Group into interval of 5 seconds starting at the minimum

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to figure out a postgresql code to group a data table into groups over an interval of time (e.g. 5 seconds) starting at each minimum timestamp.

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT
  timestamp::timestamp with time zone,
  name::text
FROM ( VALUES
  ('2010-11-16 10:32:22', 'John'),
  ('2010-11-16 10:32:23', 'John'),
  ('2010-11-16 10:32:25', 'John'),
  ('2010-11-16 10:32:27', 'John'),
  ('2010-11-16 10:32:27', 'John'),
  ('2010-11-16 10:32:29', 'John'),
  ('2010-11-16 10:37:45', 'John'),
  ('2010-11-16 10:37:45', 'John'),
  ('2010-11-16 10:37:46', 'John'),
  ('2010-11-16 10:38:08', 'John')
) AS t(timestamp, name);
```

From test data,

```
timestamp            name  
-------------------  ----  
2010-11-16 10:32:22  John  
2010-11-16 10:32:23  John 
2010-11-16 10:32:25  John  
2010-11-16 10:32:27  John  
2010-11-16 10:32:27  John 
2010-11-16 10:32:29  John  
2010-11-16 10:37:45  John  
2010-11-16 10:37:45  John  
2010-11-16 10:37:46  John  
2010-11-16 10:38:08  John
```

The desired outcome should look like :

```
timestamp            name  
-------------------  ----
2010-11-16 10:32:22  John  
2010-11-16 10:32:27  John  
2010-11-16 10:37:45  John 
2010-11-16 10:38:08  John
```

Note : the intervals are based on the first occurence of the timestamp, and not general intervals as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range)

Comment: What do you mean by "each minimum timestamp"? what defines *each* in that context?

Comment: The name in all records is John? If that is the case, why store it at all? If that is not the case, what to do with other names?

Comment: Ah, it's a gaps and islands problem. There is a gap of more than five seconds after 10:32:29, so 10:37:45 is considered a new start time.

Comment: If there were no records with 10:32:27 (i.e. exactly 5 seconds from 10:32:22), but a record with 10:32:26 and one with 10:32:28, you would show neither of the two, correct?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner not a gaps and island problem though it could be arranged to be one. See my example for what I'm pretty sure he's asking for.

Comment: @HaithamS please update your question: in its current state it is contradictory: you ask for a grouping solution (in the title), but your example output is actually a sample from your input (which also does not fit in any logical group -- i.e. you ask for *5 second* intervals, but your output contains timestamps, which are not 5 seconds apart from each other).

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want.

First we calculate a groupid.

1. `timestamp-min(timestamp) OVER ()`: this is a window function that calculates an interval -- the duration between the current time and the min timestamp.
2. `extract(epoch from INTERVAL)`: then we extract that interval in seconds.
3. `floor( SECONDS /5)`: divide by 5 seconds, and round down to the floor

Here is that query,

```
SELECT floor(extract(epoch from (timestamp-min(timestamp) OVER ()))/5) AS groupid
  , *
FROM foo
```

Then we wrap that as a subquery, and select a distinct row from every group that is ordered by time stamp descending.

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 
    floor(extract(epoch from timestamp-min(timestamp) OVER ()) /5) AS groupid, *
  FROM foo
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (groupid) timestamp, name
FROM t
ORDER BY groupid, timestamp;
```

Notice we don't do a `GROUP BY` anywhere. This because you're returning the entire row. There is no need.

### Caveat

As @ypercube(TM) pointed out,

- This solution does exactly what you asked for "Note : the intervals are based on the first occurrence of the timestamp, and not general intervals as discussed here"

So if you for example change `10:37:45` to `10:37:41` you'll see that the `10:37:41` is in a different group than `10:37:45`.

Comment: You can actually put the expression of the `groupid` inside the `DISTINCT ON` and `ORDER BY` clauses to avoid the extra cost of the CTE.

Comment: That's true, I mainly used the CTE to isolate the calculations from the display for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score -1):

The idea is to take the difference of the minimum and the timestamp.  You can calculate the minimum using window functions.  That results in an `interval` type, from which you can extract the seconds (using `epoch`).

Finally, add back the minimum timestamp to get what you want.

I'm not sure where name comes from, but here is the idea:

```
select (min_timestamp +
        floor(extract(epoch from (timestamp - min_timestamp)) / 5)*5 * interval '1 second'
       ) as timestamp,
       min(name)
from (select t.*, min(timestamp) over () as min_timestamp
      from t
     ) t
group by (min_timestamp +
          floor(extract(epoch from (timestamp - min_timestamp)) / 5)*5 * interval '1 second'
         );
```

Here is sample code;

```
with t(timestamp, name) as (

    SELECT
      timestamp::timestamp with time zone,
      name::text
    FROM ( VALUES
      ('2010-11-16 10:32:22', 'John'),
      ('2010-11-16 10:32:23', 'John'),
      ('2010-11-16 10:32:25', 'John'),
      ('2010-11-16 10:32:27', 'John'),
      ('2010-11-16 10:32:27', 'John'),
      ('2010-11-16 10:32:29', 'John'),
      ('2010-11-16 10:37:45', 'John'),
      ('2010-11-16 10:37:45', 'John'),
      ('2010-11-16 10:37:46', 'John'),
      ('2010-11-16 10:38:08', 'John')
    ) foo(timestamp, name)
)
select (min_timestamp +
        floor(extract(epoch from (timestamp - min_timestamp)) / 5) *5* interval '1 second'
       ) as timestamp,
       min(name)
from (select t.*, min(timestamp) over () as min_timestamp
      from t
     ) t
group by (min_timestamp +
          floor(extract(epoch from (timestamp - min_timestamp)) / 5)*5 * interval '1 second'
         );
```

Comment: Syntactically, you would need `min_timestamp` in the `group by` clause, but that query does not give the expected result.

Comment: @pozs . . . You were correct.  The code was missing the `*5` after the division.

Comment: This introduces a rounding error, which you're actually subject too. Look at the result set compare to the desired result set. You'er getting `38:07` rather than `38:08`.

Comment: @EvanCarroll . . . When I run this, I definitely don't get any rounding errors.  The time stamps are `"2010-11-16 10:32:27-05", "2010-11-16 10:38:07-05", "2010-11-16 10:37:42-05", "2010-11-16 10:32:22-05"`.  Why the downvote?

Comment: I think you may misunderstood the question. Your output has timestamps 5 seconds apart from each other (based on the first timestamp / `min_timestamp`), while OP's desired output is purely a *sample* from its original data.

Comment: @pozs . . . I don't want to say that your interpretation is not possible, but the question does start with " . . ..group a data table into groups over an interval of time ".  To me, that reads aggregation not sampling.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, I know, the question is somewhat contradictory, but the example output is just not a result of grouping. There are cases where OPs does not know the word or phrase they are looking for and just use some which is close enough. I think this the situation here too, but clarification would not harm either,