# How to show range boundaries when use GROUP BY time range in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

Currently I'm using solution from [Grouping into interval of 5 minutes within a time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range) to get data grouped by 120 sec interval.

```
SELECT MIN(`datetime`), MAX(`datetime`), SUM(`value`) FROM `machine_log`
WHERE (`datetime` < '2018-05-10 11:00:00') AND (`datetime` >= '2018-05-10 10:50:00')
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime`) DIV 120;
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
| MIN(`datetime`)     | MAX(`datetime`)     | SUM(`value`) |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
| 2018-05-10 10:50:00 | 2018-05-10 10:50:00 |            5 |
| 2018-05-10 10:52:00 | 2018-05-10 10:53:23 |           16 |
| 2018-05-10 10:54:23 | 2018-05-10 10:55:23 |           13 |
| 2018-05-10 10:56:23 | 2018-05-10 10:57:23 |           13 |
| 2018-05-10 10:58:24 | 2018-05-10 10:59:24 |           11 |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
```

With these request I can get also minimum and maximum datetime values from 
table records, but is it possible to show range boundaries? Expected result:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
| startdate           | enddate             | SUM(`value`) |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
| 2018-05-10 10:50:00 | 2018-05-10 10:51:59 |            5 |
| 2018-05-10 10:52:00 | 2018-05-10 10:53:59 |           16 |
| 2018-05-10 10:54:00 | 2018-05-10 10:55:59 |           13 |
| 2018-05-10 10:56:00 | 2018-05-10 10:57:59 |           13 |
| 2018-05-10 10:58:00 | 2018-05-10 10:59:59 |           11 |
+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
```

Table itself look like this:

```
+---------------------+-------+
| datetime            | value |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2018-05-10 10:50:00 |     5 |
| 2018-05-10 10:52:00 |     5 |
| 2018-05-10 10:52:23 |     6 |
| 2018-05-10 10:53:23 |     5 |
| 2018-05-10 10:54:23 |     7 |
| 2018-05-10 10:55:23 |     6 |
| 2018-05-10 10:56:23 |     5 |
| 2018-05-10 10:57:23 |     8 |
| 2018-05-10 10:58:24 |     6 |
| 2018-05-10 10:59:24 |     5 |
+---------------------+-------+
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query works by grouping on the number of seconds since the epoch, integer divided by 120 (ie any fraction after dividing by 120 is removed).

To calculate the bounds, simply copy this expression from the `GROUP BY` clause into the selection, multiply it back by 120 to get the start of the period, and add 119 to get the end. Use `FROM_UNIXTIME(...)` to convert it back to a date.

There's almost certainly a more elegant way of doing this, but it does work. If you're using MySQL 5.6 or earlier, simply replace `ANY_VALUE` with either `MIN` or `MAX` (doesn't matter which) everywhere it appears.

```
SELECT 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ANY_VALUE(`datetime`)) DIV 120 * 120) startdate,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ANY_VALUE(`datetime`)) DIV 120 * 120 + 119) enddate,
    SUM(`value`)
FROM
    `machine_log`
WHERE
    (`datetime` < '2018-05-10 11:00:00')
        AND (`datetime` >= '2018-05-10 10:50:00')
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime`) DIV 120;
```