# Postgres resampling time series data

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, time-series

I have OHLCV data of stocks stored in 1-minute increments inside Postgres.

I am trying to resample data to 5 minutes interval. I have used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27631673/5970352) to generate the following SQL query.

Here is the SQL query generated:

```
SELECT 
avg('open') AS open, 
avg('high') AS high, 
avg('low') AS low, 
avg('close') AS close, 
avg('volume') AS volume, 
avg('open_interest') AS open_interest, 
to_timestamp(floor(EXTRACT(epoch FROM 'timestamp') / 300) * 300) AS interval_alias 
WHERE 'symbol'='IRFC-N8' GROUP BY interval_alias
```

I am getting this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) function avg(unknown) is not unique
LINE 1: SELECT avg('open') AS open, avg('high') AS high, avg('low') ...
               ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Could you tell me what went wrong?

**Edit 1**: Code formatted for better rendering.

**Edit 2**: According to the answer below, I need to use double quotes around the parameter to the avg function. I am using sqlalchemy to generate the expressions and it is creating single quoted strings. Here is the part of code which generates the avg query:

```
    cols = list()
    cols.append(func.avg(self.p.open).label(self.p.open))
    cols.append(func.avg(self.p.high).label(self.p.high))
    cols.append(func.avg(self.p.low).label(self.p.low))
    cols.append(func.avg(self.p.close).label(self.p.close))
    cols.append(func.avg(self.p.volume).label(self.p.volume))
    cols.append(func.avg(self.p.openinterest).label(self.p.openinterest))
    seconds = self._get_seconds()
    cols.append(func.to_timestamp(func.floor(func.extract("epoch", "timestamp") / seconds) * seconds).label("interval_alias"))
```

SqlAlchemy should have known better to use double quotes but its generating single quotes.

Comment: Single quotes in Postgres are used for string literals. `AVG` of string is not defined. Use double-quotes instead (`AVG("open")`).

Comment: BTW using `AVG()` for OHLCV data doesn't make sense to me. I would use `MAX("high"), MIN("low"), ... first open of the 5-min, ... last close of the 5-min, SUM("volume")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2031ed1787f6fd8ebe69083f02df096f)

Your error is the use of single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"` in your `AVG()` calls. The single quotes mark texts but you want to name the columns for the average value. So you need the double quotes or can leave them (both variants are shown in the db fiddle).

**Edit (The real problem):**
It seems that `self.p.columnname` gives just the column's name, not the column itself. On SQLAlchemy the reference to a specific column is `table.c.columnname` for referencing the specific column. Please use the `p` instead of `c`.

Attention:
If you average all your data you may lose important data as the real minimum and maximum. You may want to aggregate with other functions as `MIN` or `MAX`. Maybe the `WITHIN GROUP` functions could help you.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-ORDEREDSET-TABLE

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I am using sqlalchemy to generate these expressions and I have updated the question to include part of code. It is generating single quoted exprs.

Comment: @conquester It seems that `self.p.columnname` gives just the column's name, not the column itself. Could that be? What is `self.p` in your case? I am not really into SQLAlchemy but every website I scanned (e.g. https://suhas.org/sqlalchemy-tutorial/) says `table.c.columnname` for referencing the specific column. Maybe your problem is the `p` instead of `c`?

Comment: This could be the issue. self.p is an object referencing the params which are string literals and contains the column names in this case.

Comment: @conquester Great, please let me know if this fixed it. I would like to update my answer with this if it works.