# Time interval SQL query with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I've got a table in a database that stores log data by time.  For one day there can be a million rows in the db.  The times are not at any regular interval.  It has several indexes, including the time.  What I want to do is build a query that will return a set of rows with one row per time interval.  For example, I could do a query to return 1 row every 15 minutes for a day.  This would return 24*60=96 rows.    Each row returned would actually be the nearest row in the db prior to the interval requested (since the data in the database will not equal the requested interval).

I am at a loss for how to do it.  I can't just query all rows for a particular set of indexes and time interval, as it would load more than a gigabyte of data into memory, which is too slow.  Is there any efficient way to do this using SQL.  I'm using a MySQL database.  I would be open to changing the table indexes/etc...

```
TIME

11:58
12:03
12:07
12:09
12:22
12:27
12:33
12:38
12:43
12:49
12:55
```

If I wanted to query this for a 15 minute interval from 12:00 to 1:00, I'd get back:

```
11:58 (nearest 12:00)
12:09 (nearest 12:15)
12:27 (nearest 12:30)
12:43 (nearest 12:45)
12:55 (nearest 1:00)
```

If it makes it any easier, I can also store the time as a number (i.e. ms since 1970).  In the above query, this would then be an interval of 900000 ms.

Comment: If there are more than one row for a given time interval, which row should be used?  Or should it be some composite of the rows?

Comment: Related: [SELECT / GROUP BY - segments of time (10 seconds, 30 seconds, etc)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086386/select-group-by-segments-of-time-10-seconds-30-seconds-etc)

Comment: Do you need each interval to appear?  What if there are no records?  What if one record is closest to two different intervals (i.e. 11:58, 12:27, 01:14 would have 12:14 be closest to 12:15, 12:30 and 12:45

Comment: If there are no records in that interval, then it is OK not to have a row for that interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I had thought something like:

```
SELECT 
  MIN(timeValue)
FROM e
GROUP BY (to_seconds(timeValue) - (to_seconds(timeValue) % (60 * 5)))
```

..would do it for you, but this only returns the MIN(timeValue) over the whole table. It works if the seconds rounded to the nearest 5 min is in its own col.

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/370e2/3)

Edit per Andiry, this works: ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb870/6 )

```
SELECT MIN(t)
FROM e
GROUP BY to_seconds(t) DIV (60 * 5)
```

But this just gives one row: ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb870/7 )

```
SELECT MIN(t)
FROM e
GROUP BY to_seconds(t) - (to_seconds(t) % (60 * 5))
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: `to_seconds(timeValue) DIV (60 * 5)` would be equivalent and more concise. And why are you saying this would return the minimum for the whole table only? You are grouping rows here, so this would return `MIN()` per group. (Although I think `MAX()` instead of `MIN()` would be closer to what the OP is after.)

Comment: Thanks for DIV tip, & yr prolly right about MAX() - I'm just trying to get near the target.

Comment: @deathApril nope - it behaves the same on my server o.O If I use UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t) it works as I'd expect...

Comment: @Andrew This looks promising, I'll give it a try tomorrow on our database.

Comment: I didn't bother testing your suggestion and so couldn't understand the issue with it. Now that I have tested it, I see what you mean. This seems like a bug to me. I could work around it by calculating the expression *and* converting the results to either `DECIMAL(20)` or `CHAR(20)` *in a subselect*, then grouping by the converted values in the outer select ([see here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb870/40)). But I think it should work just as well the way you suggested, without the extra fuss with conversion and subselecting, that's why I consider this a bug.

Comment: I tried this and while it does work, it is quite slow for my large database (1 million rows/day, right now 2 days of data in it).  I've got the table indexed by time, is there anything else I could do to speed this particular query up?  Thanks.

Comment: If timeValue is a `DATETIME`, storing it as a `TIMESTAMP` should speed up the `TO_SECONDS(t)` function. You might also try `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t)` instead of `TO_SECONDS(t)`. Past that, I would start looking at creating another table that stores a subset of your data - maybe 1 record a second or whatever makes sense for you.

Comment: I am already storing time as time in seconds since 1970, so that should not be a problem.  I think I may have to look at pre-processing the rows in the way you mentioned, in a second table.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think using functions is pretty easy and I haven't noticed big performance implications, although a cursor would probably preform better depending on how many rows there are between times.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TIMES (EventTime datetime)
-- skipping INSERTS of your times

CREATE FUNCTION fn_MyTimes ( @StartTime datetime, @EndTime datetime, @Minutes int )
    RETURNS @TimeTable TABLE (TimeValue datetime)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @CurrentTime datetime
    SET @CurrentTime = @StartTime
    WHILE @CurrentTime <= @EndTime
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @TimeTable VALUES (@CurrentTime)
        SET @CurrentTime = DATEADD(minute, @Minutes, @CurrentTime)
    END
    RETURN
END

CREATE FUNCTION fn_ClosestTime ( @CheckTime datetime )
    RETURNS datetime
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @LowerTime datetime, @HigherTime datetime

    SELECT @LowerTime = MAX(EventTime)
    FROM TEST_TIMES
    WHERE EventTime <= @CheckTime

    SELECT @HigherTime = MAX(EventTime)
    FROM TEST_TIMES
    WHERE EventTime >= @CheckTime

    IF @LowerTime IS NULL RETURN @HigherTime -- both null?  then null
    IF @HigherTime IS NULL RETURN @LowerTime

    IF DATEDIFF(ms, @LowerTime, @CheckTime) < DATEDIFF(ms, @CheckTime, @HigherTime)
        RETURN @LowerTime
    RETURN @HigherTime
END

SELECT TimeValue, dbo.fn_ClosestTime(TimeValue) as ClosestTime
FROM fn_MyTimes('2012-05-17 12:00', '2012-05-17 13:00', 15)
```

Results:

```
TimeValue               ClosestTime
----------------------- -----------------------
2012-05-17 12:00:00.000 2012-05-17 11:58:00.000
2012-05-17 12:15:00.000 2012-05-17 12:09:00.000
2012-05-17 12:30:00.000 2012-05-17 12:27:00.000
2012-05-17 12:45:00.000 2012-05-17 12:43:00.000
2012-05-17 13:00:00.000 2012-05-17 12:55:00.000
```

Comment: I see that MYSQL doesn't allow functions to return tables, the first link my search came up with showed it, but it [was a plugin](http://antbits.blogspot.com/2009/01/table-functions-in-mysql.html).

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a good way to do it all in one query. Perhaps someone else can think of a better way, but perhaps you could use something like this:

```
$startTime = mktime(12, 0);
$endTime = mktime(13, 0);
$queries = array();
for ($i = $startTime; $i <= $endTime; $i += 900)
    $queries[] = "SELECT MAX(timeValue) FROM table1 WHERE timeValue < '". date("G:i", $i) ."'";

$query = implode("\nUNION\n", $queries);
```

---

I just realized that this assumes that you are using PHP. If you are not, then just use the resulting query, which will look like:

```
SELECT MAX(timeValue) FROM table1 WHERE timeValue < '12:00'
UNION
SELECT MAX(timeValue) FROM table1 WHERE timeValue < '12:15'
UNION
SELECT MAX(timeValue) FROM table1 WHERE timeValue < '12:30'
UNION
SELECT MAX(timeValue) FROM table1 WHERE timeValue < '12:45'
UNION
SELECT MAX(timeValue) FROM table1 WHERE timeValue < '13:00'
```

Not sure if the `<` comparison will work 100% correctly with these string values, but I definitely think it would be a good idea to switch them to unix timestamps (or ms since 1970, if you need that much granularity). I have found it's always easier to work with integer values for date/time instead of strings.

Comment: Thanks.  I will give it a try.  The problem I think will be that I need to do this for a whole day with intervals from 1 minute to 15 minutes, and that equals 96 to 1440 queries which could be slow.