# Average of data for every 5 minutes in the given times

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with MySQL. I need the average of data from MySQL between two particular times.

For that, I'm using:

```
select avg(Column) 
from Databasename.tablename 
where datetime BETWEEN '2012-09-08 00:00:00' AND '2012-09-08 15:30:00'
```

Now, what I need is the average of data for every 5 minutes, in the given times. By using this:

```
select avg(Column) 
from Databasename.Tablename 
where datetime BETWEEN '2012-09-08 15:00:00' 
                   AND '2012-09-08 15:30:00' + 'INTERVAL 5minutes'
```

It's not showing any error but showing `NULL`.

How do I get the data for every 5mins within two particular time periods?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086386/select-group-by-segments-of-time-10-seconds-30-seconds-etc/40584023#40584023

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Group to intervals

You should use `group by` to create one group for each interval over which you want to average.

```
select avg(Column), convert((min(datetime) div 500)*500 + 230, datetime) as time
from Databasename.tablename 
where datetime BETWEEN '2012-09-08 00:00:00' AND '2012-09-08 15:30:00'
group by datetime div 500
```

This makes use of the fact that a date and time can implicitely be converted to a number, which will then be of the format `YYMMDDhhmmss`. Dividing such a number by 100 strips the seconds, and similarly dividing by 500 yields a unique number for every 5-minute interval.

The additional column I selected will give the middle of the interval: any time from the interval (here choosing the minimum, but it doesn't really matter), turned into that 5-minute interval number, back into a date-and-time number, and then adding two and a half minutes. You might use similar syntax to compute the beginning (simply leave the `+ 230` out) or (inclusive) end (`+ 459`) of the interval.

Tested using [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29042/1).

## End of range handling

Note that your `BETWEEN` range will include rows from `15:30:00` but no others from the interval started at that time. Maybe you want to exclude the end of the range from your selection:

```
where datetime >= '2012-09-08 00:00:00' AND datetime < '2012-09-08 15:30:00'
```

## Why you get NULL

As to why your query yields `NULL`: To do interval arithmetic, you don't enclose the whole interval thing in quotes, and you use singular names for time units. I.e.

```
'2012-09-08 15:30:00' + INTERVAL 5 minute
```

But this would simply extend the range to `2012-09-08 15:35:00` and still not create those 5-minute intervals you want. The way you wrote it, you're trying to add two strings, which isn't possible in MySQL unless the strings can be converted to numbers, in which case those numbers will be added.

You might want to use interval arithmetic to compute the exclusive end of the interval, i.e. the first second *after* the interval:

```
 convert((min(datetime) div 500)*500, datetime) + INTERVAL 5 minute as endOfInterval
```

Simply adding `500` instead of the `230` of my query won't work as the resulting number might represent an invalid date for the last interval of each hour.

Comment: Thankyou,I need to subtract the data between two particular times,for every 5 minutes and then average it.

Comment: @user1659213, subtract in what way? If you want values for a time *a* and another time *b* which is *a* + 5 minutes, and you want to compute some difference from the corresponding rows, then you'll need to join the table with itself. However, as your original question doesn't mention any subtraction, I'd say this is a new question.

Comment: I need to subtract the data between two particular times,for every 5 minutes and then average it the 5 minutes data. What I am doing now is:

select (avg(columnname)),convert((min(datetime) div 500)*500, datetime) + INTERVAL 5 minute as endOfInterval 
from Databasename.Tablename 
where datetime BETWEEN '2012-09-12 10:50:00' AND '2012-09-12 14:50:00' 
group by datetime div 500;

It is the cumulative average. Suppose i get 500 at 11 o' clock and 700 at 11.05 ,the average i need is (700-500)/5 = 40. But now i am getting (500+700)/5 = 240. I dont need the cumulative average . Kindly help me.