# how to aggregation data in 5mins in mysql for columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mysql like this:

[image]

I want to aggregation by 5mins, so i create a procedure like this:

[image]

But, if the student_score changes(such as add another field), the procedure need to be updated.
If the student_score table has hundreds of fields, hundreds of assignment need to be writen in the procedure like "avg(src.score) as score"

My question is: is there a way make the procedure self-adaptive for the source table.

Comment: @ArmelL., how is a view any easier? The view creation statement would still have to repeat the averaging for all columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mention of “procedure” suggests some kind of stored procedure on the database server, but I take it that you're simply referring to a piece of application code or the SQL queries it creates, right?

## How to aggregate in 5 min intervals

[Average of data for every 5 minutes in the given times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345679/average-of-data-for-every-5-minutes-in-the-given-times) also discusses averaging. As I wrote in [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12345778), I'd accomplish this using

```
group by time div 500
```

## How to handle multiple score columns

About having to duplicate the `avg` expression for every column, I see three solutions.

One would be not to create a separate table at all, but instead simply do the averaging in every query where you actually access these averages. If those queries use only a subset of all columns, then you would only have to name and average those.

The second solution would be generating the insertion query programatically. I.e. in the application from which you send these queries, have a piece of code query the db about the columns in the table, and construct the query to match. You could use this both for a real table (i.e. an insert statement) or a view (i.e. a create view statement).

Thirdly, if your scores all have similar meaning, you might be better off normalizing your table in such a way that these multiple columns are turned into multiple rows, with columns name, time, kind and score, where the kind column would be some (possibly enum) value used to distinguish the different kinds of scores.

Comment: Why does 500 stand for 5mins? Does 500 stand for 500 seconds?

Comment: Group by time div 500 maybe not enough for my situation, I need the time field be set to 00:05:00 00:10:00...

Comment: @QifaZhao: The 500 stands for 5 minutes because date to number converts to a 14-digit number of the form YYYYMMDDhhmmss. [The referenced answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12345778) also contains details on returning the time of the interval as part of the result, using `(min(time) div 500)*500` in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it almost make me get the result needed! select *,(min(time) div 500)*500 from table group by name,time div 500, return the first record but not the avg result.

Comment: This `group by` doesn't change the fact that you need an averaging function. That's the reason my reply has two parts. The first to show you an alternative to that unix timestamp modulo stuff you used, and the second to discuss the need for multiple `avg` calls.

Comment: Thanks for the three solutions. I think the second is most suitable for my situation. Actually, I need to store some performance indicator in some machines like:cpu idle,memory free...etc. The raw data which collected per second may have billions of records and make the query not fast enough. So I am trying to store another copy of data which aggregated in 5 mins to make records less.

Answer (score 2):

You don't suppose to add new column for every new type of score it most likely incorrect DB design especially if you talking about hundreds of fields, a better alternative is to have a table like

studentId , ScoreTypeID, Time, Score

In this table you will have one row per student per score type and your query above will be static

Answer (score 0):

If the `student_score` table is changed then `student_score_5m` table and your procedure have to be changed too. Right? But database design should not be changed frequently. Specify all field as they are in your INSERT...SELECT statement.

About the group by 5 min interval, try this query -

```
SELECT
  DATE(time) + INTERVAL (TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(time)) DIV 300) * 300 SECOND date,
  SUM(score)
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  date
```

Comment: In this way, the query still have to repeat the averaging for all columns.