# MySQL Average every 24 hours of 1 month

Tags: mysql

So I have a table with 100's of thousands of rows like so:

```
+--+----------+-------------------+
|ID|metervalue  |datetime         |
|1   |10        |2016-02-23 01:00 |
|2   |20        |2016-02-23 02:00 |
|3   |5         |2016-02-23 03:00 |
|... |...       |...              |
|x   |x         |2016-02-24 01:00 |
|x   |x         |2016-02-24 02:00 |
|x   |x         |2016-02-24 03:00 |
|... |...       |...              |
|x   |x         |2016-03-01 01:00 |
|x   |x         |2016-03-01 02:00 |
|x   |x         |2016-03-01 03:00 |
+--+----------+-------------------+
```

So there is some meter reading taken every hour for many, many days.

Now I need to get data for a graph. Hourly graph data is easy because I can just query the data as it is, but for "monthly" data I need to query all the rows from a duration of a month so that every 24 hours is averaged into a single row.

So one row out of 30 (assuming month has 30 days) should contain 24 hours averaged into a 1 day.

I tried this solution, but it did not work as I would have wanted it to work: [Average of data for every 5 minutes in the given times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345679/average-of-data-for-every-5-minutes-in-the-given-times)

I don't think the `GROUP BY` in that answer for example works because I don't want to average, say, every fifth hour of every day, but instead I want to average the 24 hours of a day to make up one day.

Comment: GROUP BY DATE(datetime) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still will `GROUP BY` but you do it by what the `DATE()` function returns which disregards the time part of the data, like so:

```
SELECT DATE(a.datetime), AVG(a.metervalue)
FROM MyInterestingTable a
GROUP BY DATE(a.datetime)
```

Comment: How is the DATE function different from DAY function, which did not seem to work?

Comment: Per documentation it returns the numeric day of the month e.g.: DAY(2016-02-24) returns 24. DAY(2011-05-24) returns also 24. As you can see that is not what you want in your described scenario. DATE() just drops the time part in this case, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Ahh! So that is where the problem was, the months and years were disregarded by the DAY-function! Thanks man!