# MySQL Sum of field higher than x in date range with two date fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, yii

DI've been searching stackoverflow for a while, but couldn't find a solution for my problem.

I need to check if the sum of all participants in a table of events with two date fields is higher than X. No problem so far, but here it comes. I need to get the maximum sum of participants in a 5 minutes interval.

My customer needs to know if at any point in time in a given date range there are more persons in his house than allowed.

Table of events:

```
id  start_date           end_date             participants
1   2014-03-12 10:00:00  2014-03-12 20:00:00  10
2   2014-03-01 12:30:00  2014-03-14 21:53:00  43
3   2014-02-12 10:00:00  2014-03-13 20:00:00  21
4   2014-05-30 10:00:00  2014-05-30 20:00:00  54
...
```

What I've found so far are solutions for a single date field, but I have two:

- [Grouping into interval of 5 minutes within a time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range)
- [SELECT / GROUP BY - segments of time (10 seconds, 30 seconds, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086386/select-group-by-segments-of-time-10-seconds-30-seconds-etc)

Right now I can only think of a php loop to query this, but I don't think this would very smart with possibly thousands of iterations in a date range. Also I can think of a MySQL FOR-Loop, but I don't know how to do this for a date range.

Does anybody know a solution for this problem? Is this even possible with MySQL?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

A possible pseudo query would be something like that:

```
DATE_END = 2014-03-31 20:00:00 
DATE_START = 2014-03-01 10:00:00

WHILE (DATE_START < DATE_END) {
  SELECT SUM(participants) 
  FROM events WHERE start_date <= DATE_START + 5 minutes
  AND end_date >= DATE_START

  IF (participants > MAX_PARTICIPANTS) {
    MAX_PARTICIPANTS = participants
  }

  DATE_START + 5 minutes;
}
```

A result should be like:

```
Maximum simultaneous participants: 74
```

Comment: Could you give example results that you expect from your data?  And more clearly define what you mean by a five minute interval?  *(Are you chopping an hour in to 12 fixed 5 minute blocks, or is it **any** consecutive period of 5 minutes, such as `21:48:36 to 21:53:36`?)*  Also, how many participants do you consider there to be from `2014-03-14 21:50:00` to `2014-03-14 21:55:00`?  *(Your data has 43 participants for 3 minutes and 0 participants for 2 minutes.)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added an example "query" to my question.

Comment: The '10' participate on the 12th. The '21' cease participation on the 11th. So how do you get '74'?

Comment: You still haven't defined "every 5 minutes in date range".  Do you mean "00:00 - 00:05" then "00:05 - 00:10", etc?  Or do you mean "00:00 - 00:05" then "00:01 - 00:06", etc?  Or perhaps the same but second by second?  And, if a 5 minute period has 43 participants for 3 minutes, and 0 participants for 2 minutes, what is the result for that 5 minute period?

Comment: Sorry, I changed the query to some pseudo code loop. I hope this clears things up a bit.

Comment: Also changed the dates to match my participants result. Thanks Strawberry.

Comment: man you still didn't answer!!! what does `check every 5 minutes in date range` mean??? only 0-5, 5-10, 10-15 etc... or any 5 minutes like 0-5, 1-6, 2-7 etc... Additionally looking at your data, I don't think it is possible to do that, how could you know how many participants were there in a specific 5 mins time frame in these 2 dates `2014-03-12 10:00:00  2014-03-12 20:00:00`

Comment: I think the while loop explains this. The starting date doesn't matter. Just check every five minutes.

Like this:
`2014-03-01 10:00:00 - 2014-03-01 10:05:00`
`2014-03-01 10:05:00 - 2014-03-01 10:10:00`
`2014-03-01 10:10:00 - 2014-03-01 10:15:00`
and so on

If the starting date is, than do this:
`2014-03-01 10:01:00 - 2014-03-01 10:06:00`
`2014-03-01 10:06:00 - 2014-03-01 10:11:00`
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic application for recursive queries, which MySQL doesn't support, unfortunately.

In lieu of that, what you need to do is develop a sequence of timestamps from the earliest to the latest time found in the table.  Do this with a procedure or in code in another language that calls MySQL.  Then it will be a simple matter to join your table to that and find the maximum.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't use MySQL procedures so far, but I will give this a try.

Comment: I'm using this procedure now to generate a list of timestamps: http://schimpf.es/generate-a-list-between-two-dates-in-mysql/ Works like a charm. Just in case somebody else faces this problem.