# Tricky: SQL Server-side aggregation of time-series data for charting

Tags: sql-server, time-series, aggregation

I have a large time-series data set in a table that contains 5 years of data. The data is very structured; it is clustered/ordered on the time column and there is exactly one record for exactly every 10 minutes over this entire 5 year period.

In my user-side application I have a time-series chart that is 400 pixels wide, and users can set the time scale from 1 hour up to 5 years. Therefore any query to the database by this chart that returns more than 400 records provides data that cannot be physically displayed.

What I want to know is; can anyone suggest an approach such that when the database is queried for a certain time range, the SQL database would dynamically make a suitable averaging aggregation that returns no more than 400 records?

Example 1): if the time range was 5 years, SQL Server would calculate ~1 value for every 4.5 days (5yrs*365days/400records required), so would average all the 10 minute samples for each 4.5 day bin and return a record for each bin. About 400 in total.

Example 2): If the time range was one month, SQL Server would calculate ~1 record for every 1.85 hours (31 days/400records), so would average all the 10 minute samples for each 1.85 hour bin and return a record for each bin. About 400 in total.

Ideally I'd like a solution that from the applications perspective can be queried just like a static Table.

I'd really appreciate any suggested approaches or code snippets.

Comment: Clarification: The time column is of type datetime2, with the value columns of type float.

Comment: A major challenge I don't understand how to attack is that the bin size is not known by the client in advance. The (pseudocode) query would come in from the client in the form: Select theValues from theTable where TimeKey is between startTime and endTime. I'm looking for SQL server to then compute the following logic: Okay, I know that this client\interface can only handle 400 records so what aggregation should I do given the number of records that I have for this time interval?

Answer (score 1):

some examples, if you have a datetime column (which is not quite clear from your question, as there is not table schema):

[Grouping into interval of 5 minutes within a time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range)

[SELECT / GROUP BY - segments of time (10 seconds, 30 seconds, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086386/select-group-by-segments-of-time-10-seconds-30-seconds-etc)

They should be quite easy to port to SQL server, use datediff to convert your datetime values into an unix timestamp and use round() with the function parameter <> 0 for the div.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realise you could group by on datetime columns. Will research this. Thank you.