# Get data from database with MySQL in forloop

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie in MySQL and PHP.

I have the following code to get data within a date range (day 1 to day 2, then day 2 to day 3 and so on).

```
function getData($query) {
    global $connect;
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    if (!$result) {
        echo 'MySQL Error: '.mysqli_error($connect);
        die();
    }
    return mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}

$dayZero = date_create('2017-01-21');
$dayToday = date_create('Y-m-d');
$diff = date_diff($dayZero, $dayToday)->format('%a');

for ($i = 0; $i < $diff; ++$i) {
    $start[$i] = date('Y-m-d', date_format($dayZero, 'U') + (24*60*60)*($i));
    $end[$i] = date('Y-m-d', date_format($dayZero, 'U') + (24*60*60)*($i+1));
    $days[$i] = getData('SELECT count(*) AS "b" FROM `table_name` WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN "'.$start[$i].'" AND "'.$end[$i].'"')['b'];
}
```

The code works as expected, but it runs extremely slow. My guess is because it needs to check the database each time it loops.

Is there a way to make it runs faster? Or is there any optimization that I can make?

Comment: You can skip the timestamp calculations and use `timestamp BETWEEN '2017-01-21' AND '2017-01-22'` (just an example). Also, double check your query. Doesn't look valid.

Comment: Are you only trying to get the number of rows within a given date range?

Comment: @Marc-AntoineParent I am trying to get number of rows of each day starting from `2017-01-21`.

Comment: You can fetch data for every day. From Day0 to DayN, And then can perform in php as Day1 - Day0 to get the first data and so on till DayN - DayN-1

Comment: @YongQuan Refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086386/select-group-by-segments-of-time-10-seconds-30-seconds-etc , you should be able to adapt using GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(1484953200) DIV 86400

Comment: what is your table_name?

Comment: @denny oops i missed it when i type this question. it is there in my real code.

Comment: @Marc-AntoineParent the `GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP` isn't helpful in my case because I only need the data starting from `$dayZero`, ignoring data before that.

Comment: How many rows does `table_name` have? Have you defined an index for `timestamp`?

Comment: @YongQuan I think the GROUP BY query could still be helpful, if coupled with a `WHERE timestamp > $dayZero`. Have you tried this already?

Comment: @Marc-AntoineParent I tried with a couple of variant but each loop return same result (different results are expected) which is also incorrect.

Comment: @t.niese it has at least 300k rows. And i dont understand the latter question.

Comment: If you query in 300k rows then you should define an index for all columns you use in your `WHERE` part. You should do a research about what indexs are and how to use them. In addition `EXPLAIN` and logging slow queries should help to track down slow queries and the reason why they are slow.

Comment: @YongQuan Exactly, it is intended that all queries return the same result with the GROUP BY. The goal here, as per your original resquest, is to reduce the number of queries to the database. Take a look at what is returned and compare with the results of your slow query. The GROUP BY query's response should be a mashup of your slow queries' responses.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Great question. While you can execute queries as you have done, the better option is to use prepared statements. This separates the query into a prepared statement and it's variables see here:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

The actual statement or query is sent to the server one time. After this the server waits for you to supply the variables.

This is great for performance applications (like yours), where the server is able to make use of caching to greatly speed up the performance. It is also the preferred method for secure applications where there server is protected from injection attacks.

As a final note, there are a bunch of ways to optimize SQL queries and this is just one of them. You should really always be using prepared statements though.