# Query data to create statistical chart

Tags: mysql

I have a table with these fields id, title, ddetail, date_created, type, website_id called Warning. I want query data with a given time and hava the following case(my opinion):

- If the month and year are in the beginning time, the end time is equal, I will query weekly warning for that month.(eg, 01/07/2019 - 31/07/2019)
- If both are the same year, I will query monthly warning, it mean I will count the number of warnings from the beginning month to the end month. (eg, 1/2019 - 9/2019)
- The last case is almost similar to the above case but with longer time periods. (eg, 12/2018 - 3/2019)

Example for above cases:

- Time: 01/07/2019 - 31/07/2019, the result:

  ```
   01/07/2019 - 07/07/2019: 3 warnings
   08/07/2019 - 14/07/2019: 0 warning
   15/07/2019 - 21/07/2019: 1 warning
   22/07/2019 - 28/07/2019: 2 warning
   29/07/2019 - 31/07/2019: 0
  ```
- Case 2, Time: 1/2019 - 6/2019

  ```
   1/2019: 1 warnings
   2/2019: 3 warnings
   3/2019: 0 warnings
   4/2019: 1 warnings
   5/2019: 2 warnings
   6/2019: 0 warnings
  ```

this is my solution, but I can't write SQL query. I need 3 SQL query for 3 case and fix my solution if possible.

Comment: I think I would be less confused if you showed two things: the raw data in the Warnings table, and what you have tried so far (and how it fell short). I THINK you are trying to query from the warnings table for over a given date range, but it also sounds like there are different types of warnings, and that information is not captured by the warnings table.

Comment: Oh, hang on, I think maybe you want to count warnings grouped by some interval, but the interval changes based on the range of the original query. Is that right?

Comment: that's true,can you give me SQL query?

Comment: When I wrote that I thought there were monthly warnings and weekly ones, but really that's the interval you want to group by. So I was just confused. MySQL has functions that allow you to group by month or week (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek), but I would recommend using a programming language to determine which to use. You don't say which (if any) language you are writing in.

Comment: i'm learning Django framwork, if possible, can you write query for me? i thought all yesterday but thought nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, we know that we need to select warnings, then group them by a range of times. I am going to group by calendar week to start with.

All the warnings in a month:

```
SELECT `id` from warnings WHERE date_created >= 2019-07-01 AND date_created <= 2019-07-31;
```

To get HOW MANY warnings were in the month, it's almost the same:

```
SELECT count(`id`) from warnings WHERE date_created >= 2019-07-01 AND date_created <= 2019-07-31;
```

That will return one row with a single value in it. Not very interesting yet. To find out how many warnings happened each (calendar) week, you can group the results by the week.

```
SELECT count(`id`) as num_warnings, WEEK(date_created) as weeknum
FROM warning
WHERE `date_created` >= 2019-07-01 AND date_created <= 2019-07-31
GROUP BY weeknum;
```

This will give you the number of warnings in a calendar week. If the month started on a Friday, the first week will have a low number.

To query for seven-day intervals starting on the first of the month, things get a lot more complicated. (Also, obviously the last "week" won't be a full seven days.)

To help, I first referred to [SELECT / GROUP BY - segments of time (10 seconds, 30 seconds, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086386/select-group-by-segments-of-time-10-seconds-30-seconds-etc) which talks about grouping by a number of seconds. A week is 60*60*24*7 seconds, so the answer can be converted pretty easily - but there's a catch we will get to.

```
SELECT count(`id`) as num_warnings as weeknum
FROM warning
WHERE `date_created` >= 2019-07-01 AND date_created <= 2019-07-31
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_created) DIV 604800
```

This takes the timestamp of the warning and divides it by the number of seconds in a week and chops off the decimal. So every 604800 seconds the division will increase by 1. Almost there, but here's the catch: this will tell you how many weeks it has been since January 1, 1973, and you want to know how many weeks it has been since the first of the month. Put another way, you want zero to be at the start of the month, not in 1973.

```
SELECT count(`id`) as num_warnings
FROM warnings
WHERE `date_created` >= 2019-07-01 AND date_created <= 2019-07-31
GROUP BY (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_created) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2019-07-01')) DIV 604800
```

That's pretty much it for dividing a month by weeks. I know almost nothing of Django, so I can't help you with the code that would generate the query.

But what about dividing a year by months? At first it seems like a similar problem, but there's a catch: How many seconds are there in a month?

The answer for grouping by month over a year is actually more like the original solution above for dividing by week. It works because the year always starts at the beginning of a month:

```
SELECT count(`id`) as num_warnings, MONTH(date_created) as monthNum
FROM warnings
WHERE `date_created` >= 2019-01-01 AND date_created <= 2019-12-31
GROUP BY monthNum;
```

Should get you close to where you want to go.

The two queries are different enough that you will want to recognize the different cases in your Django code and build the appropriate query.