# get avg data every 15 min

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I'm new to tsql and use mysql db. Seen an example code(at below) to get data from database every 2 hour:

```
SELECT date(`dateTime`) dateDay, 2*floor(date_format(`dateTime`,'%H')/2) dateHour,
       avg(channel1), avg(channel2), avg(channel3)
FROM `Table`
WHERE `id` =1
AND `dateTime` >= '2011-10-15 00:00:01'
AND `dateTime` <= '2011-10-17 23:59:59'
```

Then I did few changes based on the above code to get data every 15 minutes:

```
SELECT date(`dateTime`) dateDay, 15*floor(date_format(`dateTime`,'%i')/15) dateHour,
       avg(channel1), avg(channel2), avg(channel3)
FROM `Table`
WHERE `id` =1
AND `dateTime` >= '2011-10-15 00:00:01'
AND `dateTime` <= '2011-10-17 23:59:59'

group by date(`dateTime`), 15*floor(date_format(`dateTime`,'%i')/15)
```

However the query is not correct.

My questions are:

1. How to amend the query to get data every 15 min?
2. How to write sql query to get all data as well? and dateDay and dateHour columns need to be here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group mysql query by 15 min intervals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793994/group-mysql-query-by-15-min-intervals)

Answer (score 0):

1: every 15 minutes:

SELECT date(`dateTime`) dateDay, 2*floor(date_format(`dateTime`,'%H')/2) dateHour,
       avg(channel1), avg(channel2), avg(channel3)

-->

```
SELECT date(`dateTime`) dateDay
     ,CONCAT( 2*floor(date_format(`dateTime`,'%H')/2), ':', 15*FLOOR(DATE_FORMAT(`dateTime`, '%i')/15)) dateQuarter
     ,avg(channel1), avg(channel2), avg(channel3)
  FROM `Table`
    WHERE `id` =1
    AND `dateTime` >= '2011-10-15 00:00:01'
    AND `dateTime` <= '2011-10-17 23:59:59'
  GROUP BY 1,2;
```

2: all data. I wasn't really sure what you wanted. but here's every row with hour:minute in dateHour field.

```
SELECT date(`dateTime`) dateDay, 
       ,DATE_FORMAT(`dateTime`, '%H:%i') dateHour,
 FROM `Table`
 WHERE `id` =1
    AND `dateTime` >= '2011-10-15 00:00:01'
    AND `dateTime` <= '2011-10-17 23:59:59'
```