# How to reduce row set after a specific timespan recursively in SQL

Tags: sql

here is my question -

The data contains user request to a website in the format of userID and RequestTime. a request contains certain keyword is one designated search. In a given day, any request within 15 minutes after that designated search is considered as follow up search and will be ignored. so if user did 3 request in 15 minutes after first search and then a forth search 40 minutes later with same key word, the 4th request is consider a new search, any request within 15 minutes after 4th search is ignored and then start count a new request after this 15 minutes alter, so on so forth. here is the source data set

```
ClientID    RequestTime
a1  1/10/2016 11:45
a1  1/10/2016 11:47
a1  1/10/2016 12:01
a1  1/10/2016 12:11
a1  1/10/2016 12:16
a2  1/10/2016 11:47
a2  1/10/2016 12:16
a3  1/10/2016 12:16
```

After filtering, the results will look like this

```
ClientID    RequestTime
a1  1/10/2016 11:45
a1  1/10/2016 12:01
a1  1/10/2016 12:16
a2  1/10/2016 11:47
a2  1/10/2016 12:16
a3  1/10/2016 12:16
```

Any suggestion on how to achieve this? thanks

Comment: Which *RDBMS* you are using

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648693/group-table-into-15-minute-intervals

Comment: I am using SQL server 2012

Comment: Thank you Hiten004! for my case, it is not ordered internal. so the approach mentioned in the link does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the next query a couple of times until no more rows are deleted:

```
DELETE FROM T3
WHERE EXISTS
   (SELECT 1 FROM T2
      WHERE T3.time > T2.time
            AND T3.time < T2.time + 15 minutes
            AND NOT EXISTS
              (SELECT  1 FROM T1
                WHERE T1.time < T2.time
                      AND T1.time > T2.time - 15 minutes))
```

Explanation

T1, T2 and T3 are rows in time T1.time < T2.time < T3.time

You can have in 4 combinations of any T1, T2, T3 where T1 < T2 < T3:

```
All more than 15 minutes apart (combi A):

T1
T2 - 15 minutes
T2
T2 + 15 minutes
T3

or T3 < T2 + 15 (combi B):

T1
T2 - 15 minutes
T2
T3
T2 + 15 minutes

or T1 > T2 - 15 minutes (combi C):

T2 - 15 minutes
T1
T2
T2 + 15 minutes
T3

or both T3 < T2 + 15 and T1 > T2 - 15 minutes (combi D)

T2 - 15 minutes
T1
T2
T3
T2 + 15 minutes
```

In combination A (and C) T3 does not come after T2 within 15 minutes of T2
the clause “AND T3.time < T2.time + 15 minutes” is false, so no rows will be deleted as expected

In combination B (and D) T3 does come within 15 minutes from T2, but it is not sure if T2 will be kept itself.

In combination B it is obvious that the clause “T1.time > T2.time - 15 minutes”  is false, but as we ask that most inner query should NOT exists, it means that the NOT EXISTS clause itself gives a true and T3 is deleted.

In combination D the most inner clause “T1.time > T2.time - 15 minutes” is true, so the NOT EXISTS clause itself gives a false and T3 is not (or better in this case, not YET) deleted.

It may be so, that if T2 will be deleted in the first round, that in a second round T3 will be compared with a new T2 (which was previously T1 or even an earlier event than T1, that T3 can stay anyway. If however T1 (do not consider it the absolute first one) will be deleted in round 1, than T2 might stay forever and T3 will be deleted in the second round being to close to a T2 that now is far enough away from a non-deleted predecessor.

In your example - consider only the rows from a T3 point of view, since we only delete T3’s:

In the first round the 11:45 being T3 does not have a predecessor, so T2 does not exists for it and the middle query returns false.
In the first round the 11:47 being T3 has a T2 that is too close (T3.time < T2.time + 15 minutes) and since a T1 does not exists the most inner query is true too (from a NOT EXISTS-point of view). So 11:47 will be deleted.
In the first round all other times will stay (for now).

In the second round the 12:01 being T3 has 11:45 as T2, but is far enough away (T3.time < T2.time + 15 minutes being false), so it will stay.
In the second round the 12:11 being T3 has 12.10 now as T2, which is too close and as T2 is far enough away from T1 also the inner query is ok and the 12:11 has to be deleted.

In the third round the 12:16 will not be deleted as the 12:11 made room for it.

It is complex, but I hope my explanation helps.

So you need to run this query over and over until no rows are deleted anymore.
Then you are left with the desired result.

Comment: Highlight your code and click on the curly brackets button above the text window to format code. Alternatively, indent everything 4 spaces. For inline code you can use the accent mark around the `code`

Comment: Thanks Tom for your help

Comment: Thank you very much for help and detailed explanation! In my case, I would like the code to automatically do the job instead of human interruption.