# Group rows based on time intervals in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am trying to make categories through the row values.

Here are the rows:

`id` is just the unique ID, `uid` is User Id and `timespent` is the time spent on the site by the user in **seconds**

```
id  |uid | timespent
--------------------
133 | 41 | 2695
3   | 43 | 49920
45  | 73 | 95
83  | 91 | 5
29  | 109 | 2365
123 | 133 | 70
9   | 431 | 22010
2   | 445 | 15065
97  | 449 | 455
113 | 453 | 3140
5  | 455 | 44975
11 | 463 | 2695
13 | 465 | 5555
15 | 467 | 1775
17 | 469 | 55
19 | 471 | 465
21 | 473 | 380
23 | 475 | 280
25 | 477 | 3165
27 | 479 | 550
31 | 481 | 1530
33 | 483 | 2695
35 | 485 | 125
37 | 487 | 235
39 | 489 | 2120
41 | 493 | 10
43 | 495 | 2735
47 | 497 | 2700
49 | 499 | 2630
51 | 501 | 70
53 | 503 | 2240
55 | 505 | 15
57 | 507 | 5
59 | 509 | 3185
61 | 511 | 555
63 | 513 | 13480
```

What I am trying to create different categories of times, in which all these timespent entries would be adjusted.

Here is the picture of what I am trying to do:
[image]

Any idea how I can achieve that?

Comment: I guess it'll be easier and make more sense if the timespan are unique. For eg. 1-30 min, 31-60min, 61-90 min etc.

Comment: timespent is in second or millisecond

Comment: You can find similar threads, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342370/grouping-into-interval-of-5-minutes-within-a-time-range and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793994/group-mysql-query-by-15-min-intervals

Comment: @Harshil, yes, you're right. 1-30 min, 31-60min, 61-90 ... categories make better sense.

Comment: @Swapnil, they are in seconds.

Comment: any luck or hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here try something like this

```
select 
 sum(case when (timespent/60)<15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '<15',
 sum(case when (timespent/60)>15 and (timespent/60)<30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '15-30',
 from time_table;
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, it shows same all rows count in both columns rather than the one where `timespent` is less than 15 min and where `timespent` is between 15-30

Comment: sorry you should use sum not count

Comment: please try it now