# MySQL calculate Averge each 15 minutes

Tags: sql, date, datetime, group-by, mariadb

Hi I have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
 `time` DATETIME NOT NULL.
 `cpu` DECIMAL(10, 4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
)
```

And I have row each 10 seconds, for example:

```
time                    cpu     
2018-09-12 11:49:41     0.200
2018-09-12 11:49:51     0.100
2018-09-12 11:50:01     0.200
2018-09-12 11:50:11     0.301
2018-09-12 11:50:21     0.100
2018-09-12 11:50:31     0.000
2018-09-12 11:50:41     0.200
2018-09-12 11:50:51     0.100
2018-09-12 11:51:01     0.100
2018-09-12 11:51:11     0.400
2018-09-12 11:51:21     0.000
2018-09-12 11:51:31     0.000
2018-09-12 11:51:41     0.300
2018-09-12 11:51:51     0.300
2018-09-12 11:52:01     0.300
2018-09-12 11:52:11     0.200
2018-09-12 11:52:21     0.000
2018-09-12 11:52:31     0.200
2018-09-12 11:52:41     0.100
2018-09-12 11:52:51     0.200
2018-09-12 11:53:01     0.801
2018-09-12 11:53:11     0.100
2018-09-12 11:53:21     0.200
2018-09-12 11:53:31     0.200
2018-09-12 11:53:41     0.100
```

I want to calculate the CPU average each 15 Minutes. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance!!!

I'm using:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT VERSION();
+----------------------------------+
| VERSION()                        |
+----------------------------------+
| 10.1.30-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.17.10.1 |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What is your MySQL version ?

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: And define your range boundaries - for instance, does the 15 minutes start at 11:49:41 (or 11:45, for instance)?

Comment: Create MySql Event Scheduler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group mysql query by 15 min intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793994/group-mysql-query-by-15-min-intervals)

Comment: Yeah, use arturios's link, add `AVG(cpu)` and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can truncate the `time` to 15 minute boundaries (zero out seconds, subtract minutes mod 15 minutes), then group by the resulting value:

```
SELECT clamped_time, AVG(cpu) AS average_cpu
FROM (
    SELECT
        time
        - INTERVAL EXTRACT(SECOND FROM time) SECOND
        - INTERVAL EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM time) % 15 MINUTE AS clamped_time,
        cpu
    FROM data
) AS sq
GROUP BY clamped_time
```