# MySQL delete all rows added every minute but keep only 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, pdo

I have MySQL table named `datas` and column like this:

```
id int(11)
currency varchar(16)
date_time (datetime)
```

Example data:

```
id         currency      date_time
---------  ------------  ---------------------
12         EURUSD        2019-01-28 11:19:26
13         EURUSD        2019-01-28 11:19:29
14         EURUSD        2019-01-28 11:19:34
15         EURUSD        2019-01-28 11:19:38
16         EURUSD        2019-01-28 11:19:49
17         GBPUSD        2019-01-28 11:19:23
18         GBPUSD        2019-01-28 11:19:27
19         GBPUSD        2019-01-28 11:19:39
20         GBPUSD        2019-01-28 11:19:45
21         GBPUSD        2019-01-28 11:19:57
```

Must be like this (delete another in one minute only one row in each currency):

```
12         EURUSD        2019-01-28 11:19:26
17         GBPUSD        2019-01-28 11:19:23
```

And my program inserting rows about every 3-6 seconds.  but I want to keep only 1 currency price in 1 minute, and I want to delete others.

How can I do it with a MySQL query? I'm using PHP.

My cron jobs will works every 15 minutes. with php will work this query.

MySQL version =  5.7.25

Comment: what is your mysql version

Comment: @fa06  mysql version 5.7.25

Comment: `datas` sounds like a bad table name

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Have you considered doing an insert for each currency using a left join on currency and yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm where there is no match? Then you'd only ever have one record per currency per minute.

Comment: Or, deleting the existing records of a currency before you insert

Comment: @peter this program only doing fast insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```sql
DELETE FROM t
WHERE (currency, date_time) NOT IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT currency, MIN(date_time)
        FROM t
        GROUP BY currency, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time) % (1 * 60)
    ) AS x
)
```

The expression `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) % (n * 60)` will floor the datetime value to n * 60 second boundary [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52382581/87015). You can group by this expression to find `currency, MIN(datetime)` pairs within each group.

Comment: thanks man working ! Also if i want to use delete every 5 minute ? how can i use also can you add this ?

Comment: So you want to keep 1st row for each 0-5, 5-10, 10-15 minute sets?

Comment: Does your datetime contain milliseconds?

Comment: like this 2019-01-28 11:19:26 standard datetime

Comment: Haven't tested but `GROUP BY currency, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time) % (5 * 60)` might work/

Comment: ty i will test dude

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
delete  b from datas b join
(
SELECT 
    @row_number:=CASE
        WHEN @currency = currency THEN @row_number + 1
        ELSE 1
    END AS num,id
    @currency:=currency as currency,date_time
FROM
    datas,(SELECT @currency:=0,@row_number:=0) as t
ORDER BY currency
)A on a.id=b.id where num<>1
```

Comment: gives that  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @

Comment: trying again dude

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'b join

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@currency:= currency as currency,date_time

Answer (score 0):

You could use a NOT IN the min id  ( or max if you prefer ) group by minute and currency

```
delete from my_table  
where id NOT IN  (
    select  my_id 
    from (
    select  min(id) my_id
    from  my_table 
    GROUP BY currency
        , YEAR(date_time)
        , month(date_time)
        , day(date_time)
        , HOUR(date_time)
        , MINUTE(date_time)
    ) T
)
```

Comment: returns ; #1093 - You can't specify target table 'my_table' for update in FROM clause

Comment: answer updated ..  using a subquery for enforce a temp table

Comment: i tested don't delete in all of currencies.

Comment: 9351 2019-01-28 11:46:36 6.0173 GBPUSD
9353 2019-01-28 11:46:38 6.0173 GBPUSD

Comment: your query works and delete many rows but some currencies have multiple row in each minute i added before in db live output

Comment: explain better  your last comment  .. i don't understand .. the query should delete  all the row -1 for each minute ..  the min_id should be unique

Comment: 9351 2019-01-28 11:46:36 6.0173 GBPUSD 9353 2019-01-28 11:46:38 6.0173 GBPUSD this 2 rows after i run your query. and must be delete one . but still there

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper  .. for test try execute  the inner subquery an check the number of rows  retuned  for for the 2019-01-28 11:46:36  GBPUSD   ..and let me know ..also be sure your query result is correctly refreshed ..

Comment: `min(id)` might not match the first timestamp for that group!