# SQL Query that averages dataset

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL DB with a floating point data (one value for every minute) which should be displayed in an html canvas line chart.

Now to not overload the chart with the huge amount of data, I would like to sample the data values when doing the query so that the total number of rows gets averaged to `x` rows.

Can the [AVG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) function be used for this or should I write a php function that averages the data "manually" ?

Comment: Please explain what YOU mean by "sample the data".  Providing example data and desired results would help.

Comment: *Can the AVG function be used for this* Easily. Define the amount of points to be combined into one value (or amount of sample points safe for a chart), and perfirm according query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff imagine one float per minute. i.e. the current temperature in Celsius.

Comment: @Akina Thanks, but how would i do that exactly? Do you have an example?

Comment: Yes you can group by time and let mysql calculate the numbers in that time frame. If you give some sample data, we can give you a mysql example to build on

Comment: @nbk: Thanks, how exactly would that look like?

Comment: that this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2794020/5193536  and put another column withg AVG(temperature), MAX and so on  Se also aggreation functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Use [NTILE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_ntile) and group by it. The amount of groups = the amount of values in the chart.

Comment: @clamp . . . I don't want to "imagine" anything.  I would like to see sample data and desired results that illustrate what your intention is.